# SharePoint 2010: Move Default Search box to Footer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, search-box

Without using the SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio, is there a way to move the Default Search box to Footer of a page or to a specific custom div tag?
I have found CSS that will allow me to move it to the top of the page however it does not work well when trying to move it to the footer.

This is the CSS that will move it to the top of the page:
    .s4-search 
    {
    TOP: 10px;
    RIGHT: 400px! important; 
    POSITION: fixed;
    }

Answer (score 0):

There is a div-class called SRSB  which you could use to reposition the item. Either by using CSS and using absolute position or similar, or alternatively you could use jQuery to reposition or move it to a different div on the page. 
See [Difference between div id and div class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class) for using CSS & ID and for moving the elment http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Master Page Gallery through the browser, you can edit the master page to move the PlaceHolderSearchArea content placeholder.

1. Go to your site's home page.
2. Site Actions > Site Settings
3. On the Site Settings page, click "Master pages and page layouts" under Galleries.
4. Download your master page (probably v4.master).
5. Find the [asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea"] tag. Move this where you would like it on the page.
6. Save and upload back to the Master Pages and Page Layouts Gallery. Check in, publish, and approve.

I highly recommend you not edit the out-of-the-box master pages (like v4.master)--instead copy it to create a custom master page. I won't go into those details here.