# Apply a CSS class to a button

Tags: css, class

I am very new to CSS, and was wondering how to apply a class to a button. 
For example, suppose I had this class:

```
.myclass
{
background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

How would I properly apply that to a button?
I am really new to CSS, and appreciate your help!

Comment: Maybe because it is a question for which the answer should be found in a CSS tutorial. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Comment: Oh, sorry... i thought that i was allowed to ask beginner questions here, as well as normal questions.

Comment: @pattyd You can ask basic questions, if you've atleast shown you've tried to research them beforehand..

Comment: No, on Stack Overflow, it's expected that you at least do _some_ research on your own before asking a question.

Comment: And how do you guys know that I haven't looked this up? I checked on StackOverflow and nobody had an answer for it yet... I did my homework...

Comment: Although, I still don't see that as a reason to downvote this, as it may be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: div id VS. div class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the button's `class` attribute to your CSS class:

```
<button class="myclass">Button text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `<button>`, you can do `<button class="myclass">Hello world</button>`

If you use `<input />`, then it is 
`<input name="hello" type="submit" value="Hello world" class="myclass" />`