# What am I doing wrong with this simple jQuery statement to set CSS height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wonder if anyne can help with this jQuery issue...

I am trying to set the height of a div layer on my site.

I am using this command

```
var test_height = 200;
$("div#wrapper-holder").height(test_height);
```

...but nothing seems to be happening.  What am I doing wrong??

The page in context is here: http://bit.ly/1ar6KuR

Many thanks for any help that you can give...

Comment: Nothing to see here.... (rest of comment is void) `.height()` doesn't take any arguments, it's a getter only (http://api.jquery.com/height/) You're after [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: @SmokeyPHP You might want to scroll down that page a bit ;)

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - It does. you might want to check on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wrapper-holder` is [class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) not id.

i checked it in your site

class is used as add `.` before class name

```
 .wrapper-holder
 ^
```

you code

```
var test_height = 200;
$("div.wrapper-holder").height(test_height);
  ^ //changed #(id-selector) to .(class-selector)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Now I feel a bit silly!  No wonder it wasn't working!

Comment: @user2761030 You did a silly mistake but you learn a lot and now you are not silly.It's better to silly today than to be forever.

Answer (score 0):

You were using an ID selector (`#selector`) on a `class` element.

`<div class="wrapper-holder">` has either to be changed to `<div id="wrapper-holder">`

Or

```
var test_height = 200;
$("div#wrapper-holder").height(test_height);
```

has to be changed to

```
var test_height = 200;
$("div.wrapper-holder").height(test_height);
```

See the related Stack Overflow threads on **DIV ID vs DIV Class**: ***[Difference between div id and div class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class)***