# Align several divs together

Tags: html, css, alignment

Is there a way I can align 4 divs up together so they are all neatly inline, i have an image in one div, header in another, text and another image in other separate divs but I would like them to all look consistent. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KarinaMcG/6Lrdp/)

```
<div id="christmas_product_boxes">
    <div id="christmas_mattress">
        <img src="http://blog.applause.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/one_star.jpg" height="100px" width="100px">
    </div>
    <div id="christmas_pillows">
        <img src="http://blog.applause.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/one_star.jpg" height="100px" width="100px">
    </div>
    <div id="christmas_beds">
        <img src="http://blog.applause.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/one_star.jpg" height="100px" width="100px">
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="christmas_product_boxes_title">
    <div id="christmas_mattress_title">
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="christmas_pillow_title">
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="christmas_beds_title">
        <h2>Title 3</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="christmas_product_boxes_text">
    <div id="christmas_mattress_text">
        <p>This is some text in a p tag!! <br>This is some text in a p tag!! <br>This is some text in a p tag!!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="christmas_pillow_text">
        <p>This is some text in a p tag!! <br>This is some text in a p tag!! <br>This is some text in a p tag!!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="christmas_beds_text">
        <p>This is some text in a p tag!! <br>This is some text in a p tag!! <br>This is some text in a p tag!!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="christmas_product_boxes_buttons">
    <div id="christmas_mattress_button">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.downloadclipart.net/large/253-button-blue-design.png" height="30px" width="30px"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="christmas_pillow_button">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.downloadclipart.net/large/253-button-blue-design.png" height="30px" width="30px"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="christmas_beds_button">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.downloadclipart.net/large/253-button-blue-design.png" height="30px" width="30px"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consistent in what way? How do you want to arrange them?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lrdp/1/

Apply these styles to most of the containers as per the fiddle.

```
width: 130px;
margin:0 10px 0 50px
text-align: center;
```

You'll have to mess around with the dimensions . . .

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to change the way you created the struct of the html. You are trying to organize the content horizontally. You are `div`iding your "object of interest" (the box, in this case) into many pieces. I'm not saying it's wrong, but it's looks weird (at least for me).

**"Horizontal way":** http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/yUgLw/3/

Now, what about this: http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/yUgLw/2/

Its not much simpler and easier to see than the other way? Anyway ... both fiddles you give you a north to what you need to change to your code work properly. Hope it helps :)

Just a note about your code: You should not repeat the `id` attribute in your code.[Difference between div id and div class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class)