# How can I make more than one square using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a <div> square but don't know how to make another square with a different style. When ever I use <div> to make another square in css, the style would be the same as the first square.

```
CSS:                                  

div{                                  
 height:100px;
 width:95px;
 background-color:#B80000;
 border-radius:4px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:132px;
}

html:
<div>
<a href="http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/home.html"><span>M</span>i'm lovin' it<l>™</l></a></div>
```

Comment: I suggest you learn a bit more CSS. Look for ids and classes (ex. `#myId` or `.myClass`).

Comment: Yeah, I'm in intro to css in codeacademy. I barely started to learn ID but what is class used for?

Comment: Suggest you to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class

Answer (score 1):

try like this

CSS:

```
#squareA{                                  
 height:100px;
 width:95px;
 background-color:#B80000;
 border-radius:4px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:132px;
}

#squareB{                                  
 height:100px;
 width:95px;
 background-color:#B8FFFF;
 border-radius:4px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:132px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="squareA">
<a href="http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/home.html"><span>M</span>i'm lovin' it<l>™</l></a></div>

<div id="squareB">
<a href="http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/home.html"><span>M</span>i'm lovin' it<l>™</l></a></div>
```

Explanation:

you were styling all the `divs` in your `css`. the same `style` will apply to all the `divs` that you have in your `markup`. if you need to apply `separate styles` to separate elements, for e.g. two `divs`, one way is to give them both `different ids` and apply styles to particular ids.

P.S : there are a loads of other ways too. try to read more on CSS styling.

Comment: So I would need to 'name' each div by using id and use that name to style it? Can I name it whatever I want? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, generally you can name it whatever you want, just refer to those names in your CSS correctly to style. for CSS id naming conventions see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 1):

Use a different id for each one.

Then for your css

Div#first {

}

div#second {

}

Answer (score 1):

Use classes instead of ids or the literal `div` selector in your CSS. Create a class that represents your square and two classes that represent your colors.

HTML:

```
<div class="square a">
    <a href="http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/home.html">
    <span>M</span>i'm lovin' it<l>™</l>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="square b">
    <a href="#">
    <span>B</span>bee<l>™</l>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square {
    border-radius:4px;
    height:100px;
    width:95px;
    border-radius:4px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:132px;
}
.a {
    background-color:#B80000;
}
.b {
    background-color:#00ff00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mSA6E/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html "id" attribute. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cb5HL/1/):

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#red {
    background-color: red;
}

#green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put as much css classes as you like to an html tag. For example:

```
.square { display:block; width:100px; height:100px; }
.red { background:#f00; }
.green { background:#0f0; }
.blue { background:#00f; }
```

Then

```
<div class="square red">Red square</div>
<div class="square green">Green square</div>
<div class="square blue">Blue square</div>
```

This approach is also more verbose than having multiple repetitions of the same instructions.