# Regex Find/Replace in Notepad++ random id with uniform id

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm using notepad++.
I would like to find inside id selector

```
<div id="BA5Ut" class="post"></div>
<div id="k2lwuCi" class="post"></div>
<div id="4Ikfwvh" class="post"></div>
<div id="NsR8yLS" class="post"></div>
```

and i want to replace every random id with uniform id

```
<div id="upload" class="post"></div>
<div id="upload" class="post"></div>
<div id="upload" class="post"></div>
<div id="upload" class="post"></div>
```

How can I do a replacement?
So can anyone help me with regex?

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID in the same document is illegal in HTML.

Comment: Sure you want to do this? An `id` needs to be unique, for same elements on the same lvel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class

Comment: @Jongware No, for elements in the same document. That's why they are called "id".

Comment: @Tomalak: then it's even a worse idea than I thought :)

Answer (score 3):

Find

```
id="[^"]*"
```

Replace with

```
id="upload"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the task is as simple as you describe it, you could use something like this:

```
id="[^"]+"
```

Replace with:

```
id="upload"
```

`[^"]+` will match anything but a double quote character.