# Can an id be used more than once?

Tags: css

I know that a class can be repeated but that an id should only be used once, but why is this?  If I give several elements the same ID they work just as well as classes.  What am I missing here?

Comment: "*What am I missing here?*" - Valid HTML, and inevitable JavaScript errors. Please have a look at: [CSS: div id VS. div class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class)."

Comment: ...oh and CSS cascade errors too.

Comment: That _might_ work, but you have no guarantee for that, since it is not supported, officially. That means: you will run into problems as soon as you use some kind of library which relies on valid html markup.

Answer (score 0):

Not on all browsers and not for all purposes (for example javascript stuff)

There's really no reason why you would want to risk it...