# When do you use "class" versus "id"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Bootstrap to style my table, which is a basic to do list. I wanted to add a form input in one cell and check button in the cell directly next to it on the right. I wanted to use `id="check-button"`. I think when I run my JavaScript and jQuery, I would need to use class if I want to add more buttons. I am now setting my HTML and JS.

Here is what I have for the HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>To Do</td>
          <td> Status</td>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>  
          <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-addon">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="Text input" id="disabledInput">
             </span> 
           </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </td>
        <td id="check-button">
          <input type="checkbox" aria-label="...">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `When do you use “class” versus “id”?` = `I would need to use class if I want to add more buttons`

Comment: An id is good for something which is one-of-a-kind. A class is good for something which has a lot of similar structures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: div id VS. div class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class)

Comment: `ID` is use to give an element a **unique identifier**. **Id should always be unique**. `Class` is use to give **multiple elements** an identifier.

Comment: Some people claim it's never good to use an ID which is pretty extreme but I support that view as I can't recall how many times something unique on a page has been converted to classes as the site grows in complexity and scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments `id` should be used as a unique identifier. To help enforce this your HTML Mark-up will not be valid if there are repeating `id=` attributes with the same value on the same page.

When it comes to deciding what to use, consider how the element will be selected within the JS/jQuery. Is the jQuery going to use that element and ONLY that element when processing? If so, then `id` is fine, if the element is part of a group and you would like to re-use the jQuery when something happens to any item in that group then using a `class=` is more appropriate.

`id` and `class` can also be used together. Say you want something to happen whenever a group is clicked, but also want to know exactly which item in the group was clicked, you could do something like:

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="clickable"> Click Here!! </div>
<div id="2" class="clickable"> Click Here!! </div>
<div id="3" class="clickable"> Click Here!! </div>
<div id="Clicked"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.clickable').click(function(){
   // Reset the color of all clickable elements
   $('.clickable').css("background-color","white");
   // Display which element we clicked
   $('#Clicked').html('You Clicked Div: ' +this.id);
   // Set the background color of the clicked element
   $(this).css("background-color","lightgreen");
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/J4C0814N/f3x3j64n/2/)

In this example the first three divs are part of a 'group' by using a common `class="clickable"` in the jQuery I can then trigger an event for any of these elements without having to duplicate code.

The `.clickable` selector is a [Class Selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) which means that it will be triggered for any element with `class="clickable"`, this does not have to be a `div`.

The `#Clicked` selector is a [Id Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) which will select the first element matching `id="Clicked"`

Once the `.click` event has been triggered the `this.id` can be used to get the exact element we clicked on out of the three, `$(this)` can be used to manipulate the clicked element and `$('.clickable')` can be used to manipulate all elements grouped by the `class` attribute.

Comment: The `#` is for the [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).. The code does not work without it.

Comment: great explanation, Jake. =8^)