# How to get the selected value from breadcrumbs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to get the selected value from breadcrumbs.

The breadcrumbs is this way:

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li class="active">Accessories</li>
</ul>
```

I tried to do this:

```
$("#breadcrumbs li:selected").text()
```

but it doesn't work.
Somebody can help me?

Comment: $(".breadcrumbs >  li.active").text() but carefull if you have more than one .breadcrumb in DOM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between div id versus div class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/difference-between-div-id-versus-div-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
$(".breadcrumbs > li.active").text()
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/n0cfdxup/57/)