# Can't use one modal with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm working on a webpage where I have a table, which is populated by JSON.

On the right side of the table I have three (3) call to action buttons as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

When I click on the "vis" button on the first row, it opens its corresponding modal.

However, when I click on the subsequent "vis" buttons (second row downwards), nothing happens.

Below is my code *(PHP loop so as to adding more rows depending on available data from MySql DB)*:

```
<tr>
    <td><? echo $row['filename']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['cat']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['size']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['usr']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['date']; ?></td>
    <td width="18%">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="openItem" data-toggle="modal" href="#show-dialog" onclick="window.location.hash = '<? echo $row['id'];?>';">Vis</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="downloadItem" download="">Last ned</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteItem" data-toggle="modal" href="#error-dialog" onclick="window.location.hash = '1';">Slett</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My modal *(HTML code)*:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="show-dialog" style="height: auto; max-height: 500px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
            <h3>video_raw01.raw</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <video width="100%" controls>
                <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video> <br>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">url:path/to/video/raw</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; float: right; width: 100%;">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-modal btn-cancel"  data-dismiss="modal">Last ned</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Lukk</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my JavaScript code *(using the jQuery library)*:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#openItem").on("click", function(){ $("#show-dialog").modal();});
        $("#deleteItem").on("click", function(){ $("#error-dialog").modal();});
        $('#show-dialog').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            var hash = window.location.hash;   
            console.log("LOG: "+hash);

        });
</script>
```

Is there any reason why click actions on subsequent row buttons won't open their respective corresponding modals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> Is there any reason why click actions on subsequent row buttons won't open their respective corresponding modals?

**Yes**; because **id**s MUST be unique.

In case of several occurrences of the same **`id`** *(which shouldn't be)*, only the very first one will be usable and available for manipulations.

---

Use classes instead of id to resolve it as in: **`class="openItem"`** in place of **`id="openItem"`**.

Subsequently, your scripts should be edited as well to reference the appropriate modals as such as captured below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".openItem").on("click", function(){ $("#show-dialog").modal();});
        $(".deleteItem").on("click", function(){ $("#error-dialog").modal();});
        $('.show-dialog').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            var hash = window.location.hash;   
            console.log("LOG: "+hash);

        });
</script>
```

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547988/6381711), and further, [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/544052/6381711) for a good insight on the difference between a **`class`** and an **`id`** so as to understand the nature of the challenge you are facing: *only the first occurence of the **id** gets affected*.

Comment: That wont work, since im already using a class to define the styles. I tried changing it to a class, didnt work

Comment: @StianInstebo: you should use a different class then. **ID**s supposed to be unique. It should definitely work. Let me know the outcome.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, well, then i need to find a new way to bootstrap theme my links. Thanks :)

Comment: @StianInstebo: just updated my answer with a reference for an insight into the nature of the challenge you are facing.

Comment: Thanks, what i did was: 'class="openItem btn btn-primary"', this worked