# Countdown before download only working on 1st button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have got this Download button with a few seconds Timer before download but unfortunately, it is working only on 1st button but not on other buttons.
I want it to work on each and every download button properly and I am not able to figure out how to fix this issue. Please help!

I have Attached a CSS, HTML, and JavaScript that I have been using.

```js
document.getElementById("download_button").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var timeleft = 3;

  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1() {
    document.getElementById('download').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Wait " + timeleft + "";

    if (timeleft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = ""
      window.open(document.querySelector('#downloadbutton a').href, '_blank');
      document.getElementById('download').style.display = "";
    }
    timeleft -= 1;
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#download_button {
  border: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 28px;
  outline: none;
}

.button-1 {
  background: #f12711;
}

.button-2 {
  background: #0575E6;
}

.button-3 {
  background: #fe8c00;
}

#download_button:hover {
  background: #000000;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="downloadbutton" style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="http:///www.google.com">
    <button id="download_button" class="button-1">
          <div class="title">Document Title 1</div>
          <div id="download">DOWNLOAD</div>
          <div id="timer"></div>
        </button>
  </a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="downloadbutton" style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="http:///www.google.com">
    <button id="download_button" class="button-2">
          <div class="title">Document Title 2</div>
          <div id="download">DOWNLOAD</div>
          <div id="timer"></div>
        </button>
  </a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="downloadbutton" style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="http:///www.google.com">
    <button id="download_button" class="button-3">
          <div class="title">Document Title 3</div>
          <div id="download">DOWNLOAD</div>
          <div id="timer"></div>
        </button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Javascript != java

Comment: document.getElementById("download_button") will only return 1 button

Comment: Thanks @shubham Srivastava for reply. Can you help mw to fix this issue?

Comment: @RazaMurad added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the basic rule of html,

> The simple difference between the two is that while a class can be
> used repeatedly on a page, an ID must only be used once per page.
> Therefore, it is appropriate to use an ID on the div element that is
> marking up the main content on the page, as there will only be one
> main content section. In contrast, you must use a class to set up
> alternating row colors on a table, as they are by definition going to
> be used more than once...

Source: [Whats-the-difference-between-an-id-and-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/719613/6670723)

Either you can use classes or you can use different ids, or both depending on requirements.

I have changed `download_button` from `id` to `class` and added `EventListener` with loop, the reason of using class is you are adding same `EventListener` to all buttons.

Then I have used different but identical Ids to `download`, `downloadbutton` and `timer` because your function need to select them individually, I used numbers with Id because it will be easy to select with the index of the item.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".download_button").forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var timeleft = 3;

    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1() {
      document.getElementById('download_' + index).style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("timer_" + index).innerHTML = "Wait " + timeleft + "";

      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById("timer_" + index).innerHTML = ""
        window.open(document.querySelector('#downloadbutton' + index + ' a').href, '_blank');
        document.getElementById('download_' + index).style.display = "";
      }
      timeleft -= 1;
    }, 1000);
  });
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.download_button {
  border: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 28px;
  outline: none;
}

.button-1 {
  background: #f12711;
}

.button-2 {
  background: #0575E6;
}

.button-3 {
  background: #fe8c00;
}

.download_button:hover {
  background: #000000;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="downloadbutton0" style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="http:///www.google.com">
    <button class="download_button button-1">
          <div class="title">Document Title 1</div>
          <div id="download_0">DOWNLOAD</div>
          <div id="timer_0"></div>
        </button>
  </a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="downloadbutton1" style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="http:///www.google.com">
    <button class="download_button button-2">
          <div class="title">Document Title 2</div>
          <div id="download_1">DOWNLOAD</div>
          <div id="timer_1"></div>
        </button>
  </a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="downloadbutton2" style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="http:///www.google.com">
    <button class="download_button button-3">
          <div class="title">Document Title 3</div>
          <div id="download_2">DOWNLOAD</div>
          <div id="timer_2"></div>
        </button>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution using different IDs

```js
function download(btn) {

  id = Number(btn.id.slice("downloadbutton".length+1))

  var timeleft = 3;

  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1() {
    document.getElementById('download' + id).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("timer" + id).innerHTML = "Wait " + timeleft + "";

    if (timeleft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
      document.getElementById("timer" + id).innerHTML = ""
      //window.open(document.querySelector('#downloadbutton' + id + ' a').href, '_blank');
      document.getElementById('download' + id).style.display = "";
    }
    timeleft -= 1;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#download_button {
  border: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 28px;
  outline: none;
}

.button-1 {
  background: #f12711;
}

.button-2 {
  background: #0575E6;
}

.button-3 {
  background: #fe8c00;
}

#download_button:hover {
  background: #000000;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="downloadbutton1" style="text-align: center;">
    <button id="download_button1" class="button-1" onclick="download(this)">
              <div class="title">Document Title 1</div>
              <div id="download1">DOWNLOAD</div>
              <div id="timer1"></div>
            </button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="downloadbutton2" style="text-align: center;">
    <button id="download_button2" class="button-2" onclick="download(this)">
              <div class="title">Document Title 2</div>
              <div id="download2">DOWNLOAD</div>
              <div id="timer2"></div>
            </button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="downloadbutton3" style="text-align: center;">
    <button id="download_button3" class="button-3" onclick="download(this)">
              <div class="title">Document Title 3</div>
              <div id="download3">DOWNLOAD</div>
              <div id="timer3"></div>
            </button>
</div>
```