# How can I do multiple delete in js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to have a confirmation before deleting an account. How can I do it?

This is the picture for the UI of the accounts.
[image]

This is the html code.

```
<a href="uses_script.php?user_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>&username=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_username']; ?>" 
                      id = "del"
                      data-toggle="tooltip" 
                      data-placement="top" 
                      title="Delete"> 
                      <i class="mdi mdi-close"></i></a>
```

This is the javascript.

```
const deleteIcon = document.querySelectorAll("del");
deleteIcon.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const confirmVar = confirm("Do you want to proceed? ");
  if (!confirmVar) e.preventDefault();
}
```

**What I want to do is before deleting users I want to have a confirmation that when I click OK it will delete and when I click cancel it will just close.**

Comment: How you added event for array of elements ? You should loop first - also what do you expect to select is there's a tag in your page called `del` ? You should forget about `querySelectorAll` when you select just one element and use `querySelector` like `document.querySelector("#del")` also close the parentheses of `addEventListener()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the correct code.

```js
const deleteIcon = document.querySelectorAll("#del");
deleteIcon.forEach ((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{  
  const confirmVar = confirm("Do you want to proceed?");
  if (!confirmVar){ e.preventDefault();}})
})
```

I have iterated through the buttons to add the event listener for each of them and I have also added the `e` parameter so that it identifies the event.

**NOTE:** `addEventListener` doesn't work for a **collection of elements**. You will have to **iterate** through each element.

Answer (score 0):

Your listener is not applied to the element correctly.

Use a `#` in your Query Selector to target an element by ID:

```
const deleteIcon = document.querySelector("#del");
```

However, as there are multiple lines it might not be the best idea to use an ID for the delete button, use a class instead.

Add `class="del"` (or a class name of your choosing) to your `<a>` element and use the following Query Selector (using a `.` means selecting a class):

```
const deleteIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".del");
```

This will return a list of elements you can later iterate over to add event listeners to it:

```
deleteIcons.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        const confirmVar = confirm("Do you want to proceed? ");
        if (!confirmVar) e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Further reading:

- [Locating DOM elements using selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors#examples)
- [What's the difference between an id and a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/544052/8517948)

Comment: Furthermore, `addEventListener` does not work on a collection of elements

Comment: `deleteIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".del")` sets `deleteIcon` to a `NodeList`, and you can't `addEventListener` to a NodeList — you have to iterate and add the event listener to _each_ element of the nodelist, or you have to use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).