# .class vs #id: what's the difference/when to use?

Tags: html, css

'**#**' is the the ID selector, a fundamental part of the CSS language. It matches the HTML element with the given id. I know it but what is the main differences between using `.classname {...}` or `#idselector` in a .css file.

```css
.hello { color:000000;}
```

or

```css
#hello { color:000000;}
```

Comment: Note that to be valid, an HTML document can only have **one** element with a particular ID. That should explain the biggest difference between the two...

Comment: possible duplicate of [class or ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719588/class-or-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precedence. IDs have a higher precedence then class selectors. If you had the following CSS:

```css
.hello { color:#000000;}
#hello { color:#ff0000;}
```

Assuming the same element had the ID of 'hello' and class of 'hello' the font color of that element would be red since the ID has a higher precedence then the class selector.

Also, you can only have one element with the ID of 'hello' on a page. But you can have an unlimited number of elements with the class of 'hello'.

Comment: @hakiko, you may not be able to vote, but don't forget to "accept" the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

The first matches any element with the CSS class hello, the second  matchs any element with the id value of hello. For example:

```
<div class="hello"></div>

<div id="hello"></div>
```

Comment: why i am using .class or # , they are nearly same i think. Can i use .class instead of #?

Comment: @hakiko - You can only have **one** `id="hello"` in the whole page. But _many_ `class="hello"`.

Comment: There is also a difference in specificity, which determines which css rules get applied.  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity

Answer (score 1):

ID (`#hello`) should be used for unique, single elements only (for example: login button).

Class (`.hello`) should be used for elements that can be repeated (for example: navigation menu buttons).

Comment: this answer is very nice. but i cant vote you know. i am a new user , sory. i have understood the differences :)

Answer (score 1):

IDs are unique, in a way that a certain element may only have one ID, and only one of the same ID may exist on a page. So the following is invalid:

```
<div id="first_id second_id"></div>
<div id="third_id"></div>
<div id="third_id"></div>
```

Classnames however are the exact opposite. A single element may have multiple classnames, and the same class name can appear multiple times in a document.

---

The purpose of IDs, is to signify unique parts of your webpage (i.e. the header, the main content div, the footer), or unique parts of your content (message-number-149632).

A classname's purpose, is to describe multiple same meaning objects. (i.e. dialog, post, menu-item).

---

In CSS, an `#id` has a higher **specificity value**, meaning that the following:

```
<div id="id" class="class">Test</div>

#id { background: red; }
.class { background: green; }
```

Will make the div **red**, because ID is more specific than class.