# How to resolve issue with livequery using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I dynamically load HTML elements..
and used livequery() plugin to handle click events..
but only the first element could be clicked.

here's my initial DOM:

```
<div id="styleList">
    <h4 class="subPaneTitle blurred">List of themes</h4>
    <ul>
        <li class="listHeader">
            <span class="themeID">Theme ID</span><span class="themeName">Theme Name</span>
            <span class="themeAction">Action</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="createNewStyle clearfix"><a id="createNewStyle" class="btnStyle1 blurred ui-corner-all">Create new theme</a></p>
</div>
```

here's my code to load dynamically the elements from xml:

```
$.get("http://localhost/ShopNGo_Blitz_revised_w_YAML/site_styles_list.xml", loadAllThemes);
function loadAllThemes(data) {
    $(data).find("style").each(function () {
        var thisStyle = $(this);
        var styleID = thisStyle.attr('id');
        var styleName = thisStyle.attr('name');
        var styleStatus = "";
        if (thisStyle.attr('status') == "used") {
            styleStatus = '<span class="statusIndicator">Current theme</span>';
        }
        $("#styleList ul").append('<li><span class="themeID">' + styleID + '</span><span class="themeName">' + styleName + '</span><span class="themeAction"><a id="themePreview">Preview</a></span><span class="themeAction"><a id="themeEdit">Edit</a></span><span class="themeAction"><a id="themeDelete">Delete</a></span><span class="themeAction"><a id="themeUse">Use</a></span>' + styleStatus + '</li>');
    });
}
```

here's my code for the 'Edit' click event:

```
$("div#styleList").find("ul").find("li").find("a#themeEdit").livequery("click", function () { //this gets only the first element.
    var themeName = $(this).parent().prev().prev(".themeName").text();
    $("#siteStyleContent").tabs("select", "#styleEditTabs");
    $("div#styleEditTabs").children("#themeName").text(themeName);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using IDs as Classes. Check out all these questions for why this is a bad thing:

- [CSS: are class and id interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671954/css-are-class-and-id-interchangeable)
- [Cascading style sheets use “id” or “class”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670820/cascading-style-sheets-use-id-or-class)
- [CSS: div id VS. div class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class)
- [div class vs id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84378/div-class-vs-id)
- [CSS Best Practice about ID and Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298607/css-best-practice-about-id-and-class)

Essentially, IDs should be UNIQUE. When you have a set of something (like, say, edit links) the proper way of grouping them is with a class. When you search for `#themeEdit` jQuery is going to assume there is only one and return the first one, because that's the way it ought to be. You need to give the links a *class* of `themeEdit` and search for them as `.themeEdit`.

Furthermore, jQuery 1.3 has the [`live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) functionality built in, so if you are using that, there really is no need to go to the plugin for something like this.

Comment: .live doesn't support all the events yet until 1.4