# jQuery each working on only first occurrence

Tags: jquery

This is my code

```
$("#default-hidden").each(function(){
                    $(this).css("display", "none")
                });
```

its working on only the first occurrence of `id=default-hidden`, but it should be working on all. What am I doing wrong? TIA.

Comment: ID must be unique. Browser behavior for duplicated IDs is undefined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031491/whats-the-difference-between-class-and-id-in-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it

Answer (score 1):

Because `id` should be unique, you need to use class instead otherwise only first element get selected. Update `id="default-hidden"` to `class="default-hidden"`

```
$(".default-hidden").each(function(){
//-^-- class selector
    $(this).css("display", "none")
});
```

In your case there is no need for **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** you can just use

```
$(".default-hidden").css("display", "none")
```

or you can hide them using **[`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)**

```
$(".default-hidden").hide()
```