# change display of element with class x by clicking element with class y (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JS or Jquery (preferred JS) how can I change the display style of an element after clicking on another element (both elements identified by their respective classes).
The below doesnt seem to work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>


<i id="xyz" class="class1" >hey</i>

<div id="abc" class="class2" style="display: block;">lo</div>


<script type="text/javascript>
$(function() {
    $(".xyz").click(function() {
        console.log("element with class xyz was clicked");
        $(".abc").css('display': 'none');

    });
});
</script>
```

the console doesnt even log anything

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031491/whats-the-difference-between-class-and-id-in-jquery) might help you find your answer.

Comment: You are using $('.xyz) while xyz is an id you should use $('#xyz) or $('.class1') same for abc

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to reference your IDs by using CLASS syntax in your jQuery selector.

Instead of using `$(".xyz")` use `$("#xyz")`.  Same for your `$(".abc")` selector.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `document.querySelector(cssSelector)` for getting elements by class or id or `document.getElementById` to get elements by id only.
Here is VanilaJS solution:

```js
var firstElem = document.querySelector(".class1");

firstElem.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  var secondElem = document.querySelector(".class2");
  secondElem.style.display = "none";
})
```

```html
<i id="xyz" class="class1" >hey</i>

<div id="abc" class="class2">lo</div>
```