# How to append multiple values with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

On response i got multiple items, i want to append every item in response on h2 class. My code simply loop every items in one class `<h2 id="test">`

this is my try:

```js
$(function() {

  var $test = $('#test').one();

  $.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test.json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(tests) {
      <!-- <!-- console.log(gares) --> -->

      $.each(tests, function(index, item) {
        $tests.append('<h2>' + item[1] + '</h2>');
      });
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h2 id="test"></h2>
<h2 id="test"></h2>
```

Comment: Please do NOT [use the same id for more than 1 element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme#5611973)

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` — You are making a GET request. There is no content to specify the type of.

Answer (score 0):

It loops over 1 item only because you're using `id` and not `class`, try changing your HTML to :

```
<h2 class="test"></h2>
<h2 class="test"></h2>
```

And then your JS should look like this :

```
var $test = $('.test')
```

I would suggest [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031491/whats-the-difference-between-class-and-id-in-jquery).

Comment: Yeah thanks got it now.. So the id must be unique on page ,

Comment: But still confused why it's print All items on each class

Comment: @JavaCrypT still confused about what?

Comment: i want to loop every item and append all item one by one on h2 Class
for example : 
**file.json**

{ "name":"John", "name":Test", "name":"Jack" }
**it should print**
<h2 class="test">John</h2>
<h2 class="test">Test</h2>
<h2 class="test">Jack</h2>

Comment: @JavaCrypT it's still not clear what you're trying to explain. Loop through what? Both `h2` tags? And append what inside them?

Comment: @JavaCrypT the example JSON you specified is not valid, objects should have *unique* keys, you probably rather mean `{"persons": [{"name": "John"},{"name": "Test"},{"name": "Jack"}]}`

Comment: Yeah how to loop each name and print it with H2 tag with same class ?

Comment: @JavaCrypT this is another question, the original question has been answered. I encourage you to try yourself and then ask another question if you get stuck.