# Call a modal with data ajax laravel 8

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-8

I have a problem with my app , when i click the edit btn in the table then my modal is showed with data and when i click the second row in the table then my modal is not show.

[image: ss]

this my controller :

```
public function edit_kpi_program_plan(Request $request)
{
    $data = kpi_input_program::where('id' , $request->id)->first();

    return response()->json($data, 200);
}
```

this my route :

```
Route::post('/edit-program-input', [InputController::class, 'edit_kpi_program_plan'])->name('edit.program');
```

this my button in blade:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn-edit-plan" class="btn btn-primary edit" data-id="{{ $itemd->id }}">Edit</a>
```

this my modal in blade:

```
 <!-- Modal Input Program Plan Value Update -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="new_modal_plan" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Input Program Plan</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{ route('update-kpi-program-plan') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Pilih Item</label>
                        <select name="id_program_plan_update" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                            @forelse ($data_drop_update as $item)
                                  <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->program }}</option>
                               @empty
                                   <td colspan="18"><h3 class="text-center">No Data Inputed</h3></td>
                               @endforelse
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Konfirmasi Pilihan</label>
                        <select name="kpi_program_plan_id" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                            @forelse ($data_drop as $item)
                                  <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->program }}</option>
                               @empty
                                   <td colspan="18"><h3 class="text-center">No Data Inputed</h3></td>
                               @endforelse
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Jan</th>
                                <th>Feb</th>
                                <th>Mar</th>
                                <th>Apr</th>
                                <th>May</th>
                                <th>Jun</th>
                                <th>Jul</th>
                                <th>Aug</th>
                                <th>Sep</th>
                                <th>Oct</th>
                                <th>Nov</th>
                                <th>Dec</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                
                                @foreach ($dataf as $item)
                                
                                <td><input type="text" name="jan_plan" id="jan_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="feb_plan" id="feb_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="mar_plan" id="mar_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="apr_plan" id="apr_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="may_plan" id="may_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="jun_plan" id="jun_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="jul_plan" id="jul_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="aug_plan" id="aug_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="sep_plan" id="sep_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="oct_plan" id="oct_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="nov_plan" id="nov_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="dec_plan" id="dec_plan" style="max-width: 40px"></td>
                                @endforeach

                                
                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btn-save">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this my ajax :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#btn-edit-plan').on('click', function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(id);

    // ajax
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ url('edit-program-input') }}",
        data: { id: id },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
          $('#new_modal_plan').modal('show');
          $('#jan_plan').val(res.jan);
          $('#feb_plan').val(res.feb);
          $('#mar_plan').val(res.mar);
          $('#apr_plan').val(res.apr);
          $('#may_plan').val(res.may);
          $('#jun_plan').val(res.jun);
          $('#jul_plan').val(res.jul);
          $('#aug_plan').val(res.aug);
          $('#sep_plan').val(res.sep);
          $('#oct_plan').val(res.oct);
          $('#nov_plan').val(res.nov);
          $('#dec_plan').val(res.dec);
        }
      });
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, What do you mean by Second row? The Add button?

Comment: Is your `<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn-edit-plan" ...` inside a loop? Because if so, invalid HTML due to duplicate `id`s. Use `class` instead

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar the edit button sir

Comment: Please add the HTML for table also, in your question.

Comment: @brombeer yes sir my edit btn is work now!!, thank you so much.....

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar my edit btn already worked sir, i replaced the "id" into "class" on my edit btn

Comment: Please share more details. The screenshot clearly shows a modal for me. Is this a JS question, an AJAX question, or a PHP question? I doubt that all parts are mainly responsible for the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry sir i'm forgot to mention my detail question. I'have already solve that with change 'id' into 'class' on edit btn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute should be unique for every element in the page. but it is not like this with `class` attribute.

so update your button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary edit btn-edit-plan" data-id="{{ $itemd->id }}">Edit</a>
```

and update your `jQuery` selector to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-edit-plan', function() {
  // Your code here
})
```

You can learn more about it here: [Difference between class and id in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031491/whats-the-difference-between-class-and-id-in-jquery#:%7E:text=jQuery%20and%20CSS%20use%20these%20conventions%20to%20select%20specific%20elements.&text=Id%20is%20uniquely%20identify%20an,a%20certain%20type%20of%20elements.)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer sir.........