# error not showing properly due to copying of id in loop also doesnot adding design properly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, laravel

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach ($countries as $cntry)
        @php
            $currency = array_key_exists($cntry, $currencies) ? $currencies[$cntry] : '';
            $exp = explode('|', $currency);
            if (count($exp) >= 2) {
                $price = $exp[0];
                $bprice = $exp[1];
            } else {
                $price = '';
                $bprice = '';
            }
        @endphp

        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 main-div">
                            <label for="">Price ({{ $cntry }})</label>
                            <input type="number"  class="form-control carfax_report_price"
                                data-currency="{{ $cntry }}" value="{{ $price }}" id="price"
                                name="price" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <label for="">Price (OMR)</label>
                            <input type="number"  class="form-control carfax_report_bprice"
                                value="{{ $bprice }}" id="bprice" name="bprice" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <label for="">&nbsp;</label>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-update-price">
                                <i class="fas fa-update"></i> Update
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end col -->
    @endforeach
</div>
```

this is my design so basically div are generating through loop minimum 5 times depends on number of data in db the problem is when validation fails the error span iss generating on 1st input however the error is on another input + the label is not adding properly like it is making the height of div and font so much

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btn-update-price').on('click', function(e) {
        let currency = $(this).parent().parent().find('.carfax_report_price').data('currency');
        let price = $(this).parent().parent().find('.carfax_report_price').val();
        let bprice = $(this).parent().parent().find('.carfax_report_bprice').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ route('others.carfaxreportprice.update') }}',
            data: {
                currency: currency,
                price: price,
                bprice: bprice
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.msg == 'success') {
                    Swal.fire('success', ' Price Updated', 'success');
                } else {
                    Swal.fire('error', ' Unexpected error please try again', 'error');
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
var errors = error.responseJSON.errors;
                    $("label.error").remove();
                    Object.entries(errors).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                        $("#" + key).addClass("error");
                        $("#" + key)
                            .parent()
                            .append(
                                '<label class="error ' +
                                key +
                                '-error">' +
                                value +
                                "</label>"
                            );
                    });

            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

how can i show my errors label like a label and should be on that input where validation fails??

Comment: fyi, your loop produces multiple elements with the same `id`s - which is invalid, `id`s _must_ be unique

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between class and id in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031491/whats-the-difference-between-class-and-id-in-jquery)

Comment: @brombeer yes they are but i am confused i am not getting another way to make them unique and how to overcome my situation

Comment: You can add to the id the name of the ```$cntry``` so that you never have duplicate ids which is invalid, as was mentioned above.