# How to get or assign a table id when rendering your styling in Pandas

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, styles

I am trying to assign a `table id` to the rendered `HTML` file generated from `pandas` using `Styler.render()`

After defining the `styles` I want for my table in my `python` file.

I styled my table below:

```
styler = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)
```

Then rendering my styles gives me a `dynamic table id`

```
styler.render()
```

How do I get the table id or assign a table id so that I can use it elsewhere in my code?

I read the following:
[How to inject a table id into pandas.DataFrame.to_html() output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574316/how-to-inject-a-table-id-into-pandas-dataframe-to-html-output)

But this is not working for me maybe because I am not exporting from from pandas but rather styling and rendering? Kindly advise

Comment: Did you try `df.style.set_table_attributes('id="ABC"').render()`?

Comment: But I have `styler = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)` already? How do I update that?

Comment: just chain `df.style.set_table_styles().set_table_attributes()`?

Comment: when I checked the html manually, I saw two id's, the one I created and the automatic generated one

Answer (score 3):

I'm using

```
styler.render(uuid="my_id")
```

which gives a table with id:

```
<table id="T_my_id" >
```

This at least gives a predictable id, although you probably didn't want the `T_` prefix

Looking at [the template used for html rendering](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/io/formats/templates/html.tpl#L28), it looks like the table id is set as

```
id="T_{{uuid}}"
```

then any attributes you pass are appended after that. This will be why `df.style.set_table_attributes('id="ABC"').render()` gave you two ids, as mentioned in the comments to your question.

I think if you want to avoid the `T_` prefix you'd have to provide your own template for rendering, although I didn't look into how to achieve that.

Comment: render is deprecated ?