# Added some style/formatting to a Pandas html file output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ipython

I have created a Pandas dataframe with 8 columns and 75 rows and exported into html using dataframe.to_html. And things are fine.
I would like to add some formatting/style to the html file.
e.g either have the Python program insert

```
... link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

after the Pandas export or some other method to add formatting changes to the html file i.e. without manually adding etc.
I am using iPython. 
Open to any ideas and suggestions. I have also tried the Python module docx(0.2.4), but wasn't able to immediately figure out how to add in my list of lists. And there is ReportLab, but I haven't spent too much time in that either.
I have found Pandas quite user-friendly so far, despite the 1689 page documentation :P. I also see there is a *formatters=None* parameter in the pandas.Dataframe.to_html, but unsure what I can link to that or how to use it..
Again, open to suggestions to polish the Pandas html output file up a bit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not support this.  One hack I found somewhere is this.  You could probably use the same method to add a style sheet.

```
.to_html(classes='display stripe compact" id = "example '))
```

[JS dataTables from pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079118/js-datatables-from-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

check out my answer here [JS dataTables from pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079118/js-datatables-from-pandas/35849961#35849961).

In short, you can use,

```
df.to_html().replace('<thead>','<thead class="myStyle">')
```

or, use regex to match and replace a complex part as it is just a normal python string