# Why would I use an ID selector instead of a class?

Tags: html, css, class

Why use ID when you can do the same task with class?

I mean, ok I know that IDs are just for one time use and classes are for many, but what forbids me from using the class selector for just once ? So, according to this, what is the purpose of existence  of ID's in CSS ?

Furthermore, what do we need IDs and even classes for, when we can make a new element in the stylesheet with exactly the same attributes ?

The following code is an example of what I'm trying to ask:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ID's, classes and new elements</title>
<style>
    #sidebar1 {
        display: block;
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 200px;
        height: 500px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .sidebar2 {
        display: block;
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 200px;
        height: 500px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        float: left;
    }
    
    new_element {
        display: block;
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 200px;
        height: 500px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="sidebar1">What is the difference?</div><!--Use of ID selector-->
    
    <div class="sidebar2">What is the difference?</div><!--Use of class selector just once !-->
    
    <new_element>What is the difference?</new_element><!--Use of a new made element with exactly the same attributes-->
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: css doesn't really care which you use. Id's are more useful when you want to do specific things with your elements, mostly in JS. Creating new element types are handled differently based on browser and some versions (most notably older IE versions) will not respect these "custom" elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several differences between `id`s and `class`es. Probably most importantly there is a semantic difference. An `Id` needs to be unique (actually you html is invalid if you use the same id twice in the document) and identifies special elements in your HTML Document, classes are there to group elements which have something in common.

1) Searching for `id` in the HTML Tree is faster than `class` because the css processor stops at the first matching element it finds. (Thus `id` css selectors are faster).

2) Ids and classes have different [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). Since ids are unique in the document, they have higher specificity than classes. This is important in bigger projects where you have a lot of CSS rules where  a lot of overwriting occurs.

3) The difference between classes and ids is even greater once you work with javascript.

Defining new elements leads you markup to be invalid, that's why the last option is not a good idea.

Comment: +1 for the note about specificity. I think that is the more important takeaway.

Comment: I didn't know about specificity. Thanks a lot! It also helped me understand why my code had flaws and certain things in it just weren't occurring.

Answer (score 2):

Both will have the same outcome, but while a class can be used once or multiple times, an ID can *only* be used once.  If you have a unique element that will not be reused on the page, an ID should be used.  If it is something that will be recurring, a class should be used.

Some of the differences don't involve just CSS.  Later, if you delve into javascript, you may be selecting HTML elements.  If you want to ensure you will be selecting the correct element, an ID would be more helpful than a class.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing which forbids you to use classes for single elements. Imho its not a bad practise at all.

Its all about the **expressive value** of the selector you're using. Both in the html and the css you're writing. If someone else or your future self sees an ID (and you're other code looks like, you know what you're doing ;)) in one of the two, he knows or at least should immediately know that a certain element is existing just once on a page.

The drawback is, that overwriting rules gets more difficult as ID's have more weight / a **higher specificity** than classes. Depending on the strategy of class-naming and the rules you set here this might or might not be an issue.

There a lot of good reads out there about this subject. As a start I would recommend you, to have a look here:
https://github.com/stevekwan/best-practices/blob/master/css/best-practices.md

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are a few reasons. 
One is because of specificity, `id` rank higher than `classes`.
Another is based on the particular use of the object you are effecting. Is the class something that only effects the font-size, weight, family and does it need to be used multiple times or only once? 
I think that semantics plays a part as well, i.e. if you only use a `class` once, it more be more semantic to use an `id` instead.
You also use an `id` for JavaScript to grab an element from the document.

Those are only a few, but I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It is best to avoid using custom tags, as you never know when those tags may become standardized, and have special usage in the future. Also your html markup will be invalid.

I think [here](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) is nice explanation about difference between id and class.

Answer (score 1):

What you have bumped into is the CSS concept of *specificity*. Classes, IDs and element selectors are only 3 of over [30 selectors](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/), which means that there must be rules to govern the priorities.

Calculating specificity is [quite complicated](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), but in most cases it looks more or less like this (higher priority selectors are first):

- In-tag style definitions
- IDs
- Classes
- Elements
- Everything (*)

When it comes to the specifics of ID or Class, I treat it as a matter of style and semantics: an ID should be used with something that is unique, while a Class is intended to be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

One big reason “JavaScript”. Imagine trying to use javascript without Id’s