# Retrieve different value from same <button>

Tags: jquery, html

I have been facing some problems regarding to retrieve different value from same button with the same ID.

This is the code of my HTML.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPromote" value="1">Promote</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPromote" value="2">Promote</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPromote" value="3">Promote</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPromote" value="4">Promote</button>
```

So, as you can see there are different values in the same ID buttons.

Is there any method using retrieve the value by using **JQuery** without using any for loop?

This is the method I am using right now. But I found it is not efficiency.
Because it has to generate the button with different index first and also the button ID too.

Imaging I have 1000 buttons to load, my web browser will not responding. (Low specification computer)

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $("btnPromote" + i).click(function() {
        blah ...
    });
}
```

Therefore I seek for help and looking for some efficiency method to do it.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: `id` should be unique

Comment: It's going to be a hideous looking web page...

Comment: @PranavCBalan, if my ID is unique, then at my JQuery also need to define the actual number of the button I had.
What if I had 1000 buttons? :(

Comment: @scrowler, it's true. You will see a bump of BUTTONS appear on your source. Hahaha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you should use a [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it) instead of an id for this. Then, you can use this to simplify your code:

```
$(".btnPromote").click(function(event) {
    // do something with event.target
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/MSB4m/

Comment: @J David Smith, Thank you so much. I would like to try it immediately. Hopefully my question is not stupid for you. :(

Answer (score 1):

you can't give same id's for different objects, use class instead of id. Then you can retrieve the values like

```
$(".btn-primary").each(function(){
alert($(this).val());

});
```

you can also bind the click event for buttons with,

```
$("body").on("click",".btn-primary",function(){
 alert($(this).val());
 });
```