# How would I remove an ID and the add a different ID to my nav ul

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a different ID to my nav's ul-list.

What am I doing wrong?

Can you add and remove ID's in jQuery or do I need to use JavaScript?

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() == 0) {
            $('#logo_top').removeClass('remove-logo');
        } else {
            $('#logo_top').addClass('remove-logo'); 
        }
    });
    $(function(){
        $('#navi').data('size','big');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
        {
            if($('#navi').data('size') == 'big')
            {
                $('#navi').data('size','small');
                $('#navi').stop().animate({
                    height:'58px'
                },600);
                $('#navi-top ul').remove();
                $('#navi-top-small ul').add(); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($('#navi').data('size') == 'small')
            {
                $('#navi').data('size','big');
                $('#navi').stop().animate({
                    height:'122px'
                },600);
            }  
        }
    });
```

this is the html for my site im trying to target the ul any suggestions?

```
<div id="navi-top" class="push-off-right-s">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">The Group</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Working Together</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Paymaster</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Claybrook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vote for a sidekick</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Aaand where are you trying to add the ID?

Comment: you can manipulate the ID but i dont think thats wise.. `.attr('id', 'newID')` would do it.

Comment: #navi-top-small ul thats the ID i wana add i want to remove the original one......or can i add and remove css property instead of changing the entire ID. the value im trying to target in the css is margin: 32px 0 0 0 i need to set it to margin: -32px 0 0 0 when the user scrolls down the page

Comment: I've never actually come across a situation where I needed to remove or rename Id's (or where it was appropriate)...  I would stick to just switching around classes instead... It's doable, but you open yourself up to a lot of headache potentially...

Comment: why would it not be wise? i updated my code above

Comment: Why not use the `addClass` and `removeClass` as used on `#logo_top`?

Comment: This line `$('#navi-top ul').remove();` remove's that entire list from the DOM, fyi.

Comment: add() method wrong. I think you are trying to append() or addClass()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element `id` should be used to identify an element. If you want to dynamically change the CSS then you should use a `class`. See [Difference between id and class in CSS and when to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it)

So the lines

```
$('#navi-top ul').remove();
$('#navi-top-small ul').add();
```

should be something like

```
$('#navi-top').addClass('navi-top-small');
```

CSS:

```
.navi-top-small ul {
    margin: -32px 0 0 0;
}
```

Then depending on what your needs are you might want to add a `removeClass('navi-top-small')` in your `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The ID is an attribute value you set by passing it as a parameter:

```
$('#navi-top ul').attr('id','your value');
```

Comment: so how would i change it? like do i say $('#navi-top ul').attr('id','your value').remove();

Comment: If you want to remove the attribute you need to use `.removeAttr("id")`. ie. `$('#navi-top ul').removeAttr("id");`.
But to be honest I'd rather use classes instead: `$('#navi-top ul').removeClass('your class name').addClass('new class name');`