# Update two divs on one ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to update two divs with one ajax request only. However following code clears out both the divisions without updating the data. Please have a look at my code:

**AJAX Request File**

```
<div class='subtotal_<?php echo $row['productid']; ?>'>
    <p>Subtotal: <?php echo $subtotal; ?></p>
</div>
<div id='totalamount'>
    <p>Totalamount: <?php echo round($total); ?></p>
</div>

var productid = $(this).attr('class');
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_changequantity.php",
        data: {type:type,quantity:quantity,productid:productid},
        success: function(option)
        {
            var html = $(option);
            $('#totalamount').empty();
            $('.subtotal_'+productid).replaceWith(("#subtotal",html));
            $('#totalamount').replaceWith(("#totalamount",html));
        }
    });
```

**Ajax File**

```
<div id='subtotal'>
    <p>Subtotal: <?php echo $subtotal; ?></p>
</div>
<div id='totalamount'>
    <p>Total Amount: <?php echo $totalamount; ?></p>
</div>
```

Both the divs after successful ajax request get blank. No data coming in. Can anyone help finding the mistake here?

Comment: what does `option` return?

Comment: you should probably use `.html()` and not `.replaceWith()`. And also, your current `replaceWith` has wrong syntax usage.

Comment: I've Ajax File code in my question, it's not the same as in my current code, but yes that's how it looks like, php & html code, if you want to have a look at same exact content, I could paste the whole file here

Comment: @ShaunakD Wrong syntax? Where?

Comment: `replaceWith(("#subtotal",html)` - this.

Comment: Okayh, so can you tell me what's right? Because I got the reference from another source.

Comment: Try just using `$('#totalamount').html(option);` And see what happens in the div.

Comment: try using an alert to see if ur receiving any data

Comment: One more thing, I have totally working code with my one div update. So `$('#totalamount').html(html)` with no `<div id='subtotal'>` in ajax like works perfectly, I'm having difficulty only updating two divs in one ajax request.

Comment: I'm receiving data. @Mr.coder

Comment: Do you have a div `$('.subtotal_'+productid)`

Comment: @ShaunakD Yeah buddy, I've that

Comment: @ShanilSoni show your html too

Comment: You can have a look, not whole code has been pasted, but pasted what was required, mainly to see that `divs` exist.

Comment: use `alert` and see whether you are getting `productid`, nd also verify if your code in wrapped in Document ready

Comment: Yup everything is working perfectly fine, I checked that already, then I put the question here, and it's a live file, project is almost completed except this.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample snippet to make GET requests and update multiple elements at once. You can modify the same to make POST requests.
Hope this helps.

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com/",
            success: function(option){
                //do stuff
            }
        })).then(function( option ) {
        //update html
        $('.div1').html('URL: ' + option.id);
        $('.div2').html('Shares: ' + option.shares);
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8kWJ/)

Comment: What is id & shares in `option.id` & `option.shares`, divs?

Comment: It's just sample data I used to demonstrate.

Comment: Yeah but `shares` in nowhere in your data, where is it coming from?

Comment: Can it be like this `option.div id='xyz'` ? I've no idea about this syntax, can you help putting a div?

Comment: This(http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com/) url returns a JSON. So, both .id and .shares came from that JSON.
Update like: 
<div id="div1">div 1</div> $('#div1').html(somedata);

And, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it

Comment: That SOMEDATA is not working in my code, I used this to replace my one div `replaceWith(("#subtotal",html));` & for another second such request.

Comment: Sorry man! I can't spoonfeed. Learn Javascript basics before.

Comment: Thanks anyway & it's not about basics, it's about the mistake that I'm not getting at. Above code is valid FYI