# animate.css: How do you have the css animation work only the first time?

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css

I'm using animate.css and the animation occurs every time i refresh or return from another page; how do i make it so that once the index.html is visited, and I go to another .html or refresh the page, the li does not occur again?

```
index.html
<div id="sidebar" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
  <nav id="sidebar-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="side-post" class="animated bounceInLeft" ui-sref="timeline">Timeline</a>
      <li><a id="side-post" class="animated bounceInLeft" ui-sref="skills">Skills</a>
      <li><a id="side-post" class="animated bounceInLeft" ui-sref="personal_interests">Interests</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

```
style.css 
#side-post {
 animation-delay:0.7s;
 -moz-animation-delay:0.7s;
 -webkit-animation-delay:0.7s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a proper way that you can make the animation run for **the first time** but not when you're back from another page or refreshing. If you do that, you may not see the animation neither when you re-open the webpage.

If you have to implement this, try to store a 'timestamp' in the local storage so that you can allow the animation run after a while, eg 5 minutes later.

```
var now = Date.now();

if ('lastOpened' in localStorage) {
  if (now - localStorage.lastOpened > 5 * 60 * 1000) { // 5 mins
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.side-post')).forEach(function(el){
      el.classList.add('animation'); // add `animation` class to each `li` element implement the animation 
    })
  }
} else {
  localStorage.lastOpened = now;
}
```

Also, you should assign the same `id` to only one element, use `class` instead. Check out [this post - Difference between id and class in CSS and when to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it) for more details.