# Allow float element to overflow horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="hold">
    <div id="hold-left">content</div>
    <div id="hold-right">content</div>
</div>
```

`hold-left` floats to the left and `hold-right` floats to the right. The widths are 40% and 55% when the page is loaded. The thing is, `hold-right` is a sort of preview of something and the user needs to be able to resize it.

This is easily done using JavaScript (the user selects a zoom level radio button), however the issue I am now facing is that, if it is enlarged, it drops down beneath `hold-left`. What I'd like it to do is float over freely to the outside of the parent div.

How do I go about this? Can it be done through CSS at all, or do I need to dynamically resize the parent every time I resize `hold-right`?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I find it hard to visualize what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you're just looking for `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a left margin on `.hold-right`?

```
.hold-left{
  float:left;
  width:40%;
}
.hold-right{
  margin-left:45%;
}
```

Also, generally you should use classes, not IDs.

Comment: @Aprillion Classes are re-usable. Using IDs in CSS is (or should be) rare.

Comment: just because you have an opinion doesn't mean it must be general. both classes and ids have their place, e.g. notice the `#12889421` part of a direct link to an answer that talks about this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it/12889421#12889421

Comment: @Aprillion it's not an opinio. Look up the word 'generally' - classes appear more than IDs. This two-column style is likely to be reused.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with display: table, and table-cell.
The table will need to be 100% width and no width specified for table-cell. Then the content will "resize" the cells.

Otherwise, you will need to use javascript to update both cells.

Answer (score 0):

Use position property in css. [Checkout this](https://jsfiddle.net/8wgp9yrt/)

position: relative; in the parent.
position: absolute; in the each child.

```
#hold {
  position: relative;
}

#hold-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#hold-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

#zoomLevelSelector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```