# How to remove appended div on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I want to remove the cloned html when I click this, what is the best way? how to detect that it's what I've clicked on `X`

[image]

and this is the HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Fields</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                            <a id="close" class="pull-right" href="#">
                              <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <select class="form-control" name="custom_form[type]" required>
                                <option value="">Type</option>
                                <option>text</option>
                                <option>textarea</option>
                                <option>radio</option>
                                <option>checkbox</option>
                            </select>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="customform[label]" placeholder="Label" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" id="add_attribute" class="btn btn-default">+ Add attribute</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is what I've used to clone the fields when I click the button `+ Add Attribute`

```
<div class="clone-field hide">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                <a id="close" class="pull-right" href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <select class="form-control" name="custom_form[type]" required>
                    <option value="">Type</option>
                    <option>text</option>
                    <option>textarea</option>
                    <option>radio</option>
                    <option>checkbox</option>
                </select>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="customform[question]" placeholder="Question" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".container").on("click", "#add_attribute", function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        alert("ok");
        var append_att = $(".clone-field").html();

        $(".field").append(append_att);
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT1**
the close is already done, so I added one more since it's still same concept,

How to add `<input type="text" name="customform[option]" placeholder="Ex. Male,Female" />` when I select `Type` = `radio,select,checkbox` and remove if it's not, then put it under on the `Label input`?

[image]

currently I have

```
$(".container").on("click", "#add_attribute", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var append_att = $(".clone-field").html();

    $(".fields").append(append_att);
}).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('.field').remove();
}).on('change', '.field-type', function(){
    var input_option = '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="customform[option]" placeholder="Ex. Male,Female" /> ';
    var valueSelected = this.value;

    if(valueSelected == 'radio' || valueSelected == 'select')
        //append
    else
        //remove
});
```

**EDIT2**
I've added this hidden input text
[image]

how to find closest into removeClass('hide')/addClass('hide') of my  base on `Type` = `radio,select`

**EDIT3 - MY TOTAL ANSWER**

```
$(".container").on("click", "#add_attribute", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var append_att = $(".clone-field").html();

    $(".fields").append(append_att);
}).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('.field').remove();
}).on('change', '.field-type', function(){
    var inputType = this.value;
    var panel = $(this).closest('.panel-body');

    var inputs = panel.find('input');
    inputs.last().val("");

    if(inputType=='radio' || inputType=='select') {
        inputs.last().removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        inputs.last().addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: On the click event of 'x' , you need to find the parent container and use .remove() command

Comment: ids are singular, you need to use classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are using duplicate `id=close`. Use `class=close` instead like following.

```
<a class="close" class="pull-right" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</a>
```

And your `js` for removing item should be like this.

```
$('.container').on('click', '.close', function(){
    $(this).closest('.col-md-6').remove();
});
```

**Update**

```
$('.container').on('click', 'select.form-control', function () {
    var input_type = this.value;
    var panel = $(this).closest('.panel-body');

    var inputs = panel.find('input');


    if (input_type == 'radio' || input_type == 'select') {
        if (inputs.length > 1) {
            inputs.last().removeClass('hide');
        }
        else {
            var input_option = '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="customform[option]" placeholder="Ex. Male,Female" /> ';
            panel.append(input_option);
        }
    } else {
        if (inputs.length > 1)
            inputs.last().addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: hello I've added new, how to do append base he select on option?

Comment: if it is only `radio` or `select` else remove

Comment: yeah when I select `radio`, it added `<input>` then select `select`, it added again new `<input>` so double added...

Comment: what does this result ? `var panel = var inputs = $(this).closest('.panel-body');`, cause I've got error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'var'`

Comment: nvm, just removed `var inputs = ` and it works... thanks bro

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake & you are welcome. @StormSpirit

Comment: wait, I just put already the `<input name="customform[option]">` to stay the loop of array even if it's empty, how to do just hide and show only?

Comment: how to change it into `removeClass('hide')`/`addClass('hide')` of my `<input name="customform[option]">`

Answer (score 1):

Two simple steps:

- change `#close` to class `.close`. You should not duplicate ids.
- add some class to `col-md-6` container to be able to select it later. You *could* use `col-md-6` too but you don't want to tie JS code to layout specific classes

HTML becomes:

```
<div class="clone-field hide">
    <div class="block col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                <a class="close" class="pull-right" href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <select class="form-control" name="custom_form[type]" required>
                    <option value="">Type</option>
                    <option>text</option>
                    <option>textarea</option>
                    <option>radio</option>
                    <option>checkbox</option>
                </select>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="customform[question]" placeholder="Question" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you also need to add once more click handler similar to what you already have:

```
$(".container").on("click", "#add_attribute", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("ok");
    var append_att = $(".clone-field").html();

    $(".field").append(append_att);
})
.on('click', 'close', function() {
    $(this).closest('.block').remove();
});
```

Comment: hello I've added new, how to do append base he select on option?

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery.closest() https://api.jquery.com/closest/ to travel from the button you clicked back to the parent container that holds all the panel

```
$('#close').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.clone-field').remove();
});
```

`.clone-field` is the top most DIV of the panel to delete

Edit:
Also, [Difference between id and class in CSS and when to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it)