# ID name and class name specification

Tags: html

In HTML we use id's and classes. we can choose any name for id.Can we choose any name for class also? Or is there any specification name for classes ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between id and class in CSS and when to use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML 5 specification:

[ID:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.
>
> There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in
>   particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start
>   with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.

[Class:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes)

> The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a set of
>   space-separated tokens representing the various classes that the
>   element belongs to.
>   The classes that an HTML element has assigned to it consists of all
>   the classes returned when the value of the class attribute is split on
>   spaces. (Duplicates are ignored.)

Also, there are style guides that define good and very used pattern for choose the values to use for id or classes, etc. I recommend you [this one from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp).