# How should I modify this code so it works with severel id's?

Tags: javascript, css, visibility, display

```
    <script>
        var toggleVisibility = function(element) {
        if(element.style.display=='block'){element.style.display='none';}
        else {element.style.display='block';}
        };
    </script>
```

I got this code from another site and in my div, which should change from display:none to display:block when something is clicked, doesnt work with severel div id's from css :/

I got this in my div which should be clicked to make others divs visible:

```
    <div id="profile_button_box" onclick="toggleVisibility(document.getElementById('testt'))">
```

I read that this only can have one ID but how should I modify the code to be able to handle severel divs with one click?

Comment: Use classes instead

Comment: do you know how to modify the code for classes? :O @EdHeal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your javascript a little to make it more accommodating for multiuse, also as many people have said it's alway's best to use classes and IDs are meant to be unique

```js
toggleVisibility = function(a) {
  var selector = document.querySelectorAll(a);
  for (let i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
    if (selector[i].style.display == 'block') {
      selector[i].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      selector[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.example {
  display: flex;
}
#testt {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.testt {
  background: darkorange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
pre {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div id="testt"></div>
  <div id="testt"></div>
  <div id="testt"></div>
  <div id="testt"></div>
  <div id="testt"></div>
  <div id="testt"></div>
</div>

<div class="example">
  <div class="testt"></div>
  <div class="testt"></div>
  <div class="testt"></div>
  <div class="testt"></div>
  <div class="testt"></div>
  <div class="testt"></div>
</div>

<div class="example">
  <pre></pre>
  <pre></pre>
  <pre></pre>
  <pre></pre>
  <pre></pre>
  <pre></pre>
</div>

<div id="profile_button_box" onclick="toggleVisibility('#testt')">test IDs</div>
<div id="profile_button_box" onclick="toggleVisibility('.testt')">test classes</div>
<div id="profile_button_box" onclick="toggleVisibility('pre')">test tags</div>
```

You'll notice for ID's I start the ID name with `#` for classes I start with `.` and for tags I just write the tag name (this is the same as CSS).

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Of course, a much better way to do this (much less code) would be to toggle a hidden class. Like so.

```js
toggleVisibility = function(a) {
  var selector = document.querySelectorAll(a);
  for (let i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
    selector[i].classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
};
```

```css
.example {
  display: flex;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#testt {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div id="testt"></div>
  <div id="testt"></div>
  <div id="testt"></div>
  <div id="testt"></div>
  <div id="testt"></div>
  <div id="testt"></div>
</div>
<div id="profile_button_box" onclick="toggleVisibility('#testt')">Button</div>
```

You use it the same as the code above, but it uses a lot less JS.

Comment: thanks :) this worked dunno what all the div stuff is you posted but i included the script in my head and used that onclick attribut in my div :) @andrew-bone

Answer (score 2):

name a class and try like this..

```
<div id="profile_button_box" class="profileButton">
```

In **JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('profileButton');
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        var button = buttons[i];
        button.onclick = function(element) {
            if(element.style.display=='block'){
                  element.style.display='none';
            } else {
                  element.style.display='block';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OR** in **jQuery**

```
 $(document).on('click', '.profileButton', function(element){
          if(element.style.display=='block'){
                  element.style.display='none';
          } else {
                  element.style.display='block';
          }
 });
```

for toggle operation you can simply write and use class like..

```
<style>
    .hide { display: none; }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.profileButton', function(element){
            // here we used classToggle property to hide/display the element
            $(element).toggleClass('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ok this looks great but how do i activate this $? I want this function to be true when i click on a div :)

Comment: jQuery for jQuery sake is a no, in my opinion if it's not already being used for the project no need to load an entire library for just this

Comment: no :O i guess this is not pure javascript, is it possible to do that only with java? im programming an app and the only thing allowed is javascript :/  @Sarath

Comment: I got the javascript part in the head now but how do i call that function when i click on mz div with the onclick method? @Sarath

Comment: Yes but i still need a onclick somewhere to activate the javascript part and change the class in the respectiv div OR?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to toggle many divs, you'll need to assign them all the same class and use `document.querySelectorAll('.myClass')`.  Keep in mind though, this will return a `NodeList` which you'll need to iterate over to apply the style to each div.

Answer (score -1):

[Orginal post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889421/5328750)

> Use a **class** when you want to consistently style **multiple elements**
> throughout the page/site. Classes are useful when you have, or
> possibly will have in the future, more than one element that shares
> the same style. An example may be a div of "comments" or a certain list style to use for related links.
>
> Additionally, a given element can have more than one class associated
> with it, while an element can only have one id. For example, you can
> give a div two classes whose styles will both take effect.
>
> Furthermore, note that classes are often used to define behavioral
> styles in addition to visual ones. For example, the jQuery form
> validator plugin heavily uses classes to define the validation
> behavior of elements (e.g. required or not, or defining the type of
> input format)
>
> Examples of class names are: tag, comment, toolbar-button,
> warning-message, or email.
>
> Use the **ID** when you have a **single element** on the page that will take
> the style. Remember that IDs must be unique. In your case this may be
> the correct option, as there presumably will only be one "main" div on
> the page.
>
> Examples of ids are: main-content, header, footer, or left-sidebar. A
> good way to remember this is a class is a type of item and the id is
> the unique name of an item on the page.