# jQuery works on 1st element in a php loop

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to change an icon with a loading icon when clicked on a link.
This is happening in a `foreach` loop in php/html code.

jQuery works fine, but only in the 1st result. In other results it does not work.

HTML:

```
<p id= "like">
    <a  href="..Link" id="like" class="external"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#like").click(function() {
    $("#like").toggle('1000');
    $("i", this).toggleClass("icon-loading3");
                });
```

All I want to do is change the class from icon-thumbs-up to icon-loading3
and remove the link!

Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: instead of `id` use `class`

Comment: use class instead of id and instead of simple click use $(document).on("click","selector",function(){}) as mentionted in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work fine:

```
$(".external").click(function(){
  $(this).find("i").addClass("icon-loading3").removeClass('icon-thumbs-up');
  $(this).parent().html($(this).html());
})
```

Comment: All of the answers are amazing, but yours works the best for me!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ids and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it) in HTML, rename id="like" to class="like-main
" or something familiar.

Behaviour is right as DOM only stores first value with a given ID.

Answer (score 0):

change id to class like the following

html:

```
<p class= "like">
    <a  href="..Link" class="like" class="external"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
</p>
```

jquery:

```
$(".like").click(function() {
    $(".like").toggle('1000');
    $("i", this).toggleClass("icon-loading3");
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using it in forach loop then use `class` not `id`. On the one page there should be unique id for each element.

So please do it like:

```
<p class="like">
    <a  href="..Link" class="anchor_like" class="external"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
</p>

$(document).on('click','.like',function() {
    $(this).toggle('1000');
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass("icon-loading3");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your answers are amazing. diavolic's answer worked best for me! ;)