# Accessing my li tag using the class of my ul tag

Tags: css

I have a ul tag and I want to access the a tag and change its style, this code works.

```
ul li a{ font-weight: bold !important; }
```

But when I put a class to the ul and use it. It does not work

```
ulClass li a{ font-weight: bold !important; }
```

Comment: did you try `.ulClass` ? with a '.' before the class name?

Comment: You missed a dot for the classname : `.ulClass li a { ...`

Comment: yes I have tried that @Danield

Comment: please post sample code showing the problem and we'll be able to help you

Comment: yes I have tried that @Chaska

Comment: If the class named `my-class` you should use `ul.my-class`, wouold you try this?

Comment: Having `!important` in there is something you rather want to avoid to begin with. What your actual/ current problem is, is not reproducible with what you have shown - please go read [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried changing the class to id and replaced the css.

From this

```
.ulClass li a {font-weight: bold !important;}
```

To this and it worked.

```
#ulId li a {font-weight: bold !important;}
```

I don't know whats the difference can someone explain to me?

Comment: The first one is selecting elements which classname is ulClass, the second one is selecting an element which id is ulId. Class name and ID are different attributes.

Comment: please show me you ul html tag. Hope you have written <ul class="ulClass"> @jonas

Comment: Yes and what's the difference? I want to select elements with that class and change it. But using id it works @Chaska

Comment: Yes I have <ul class="ulClass"> @Sonia

Comment: Suggest you refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it , and there are number of reason failed selecting the elements by class name, you better provide html code as well to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Apply below syntax and try again.here you should use  `.`  before the class name

```
ul.class li a { font-weight: bold !important; }
```

or

```
.class li a { font-weight: bold !important; }
```

Comment: Use a ID instead of Class name and let me know what the result is.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonas So ideally it should work with class.
It could be one of the two IMO :

- some basic error in the html skeleton
- you've got a conflicting css rule (with `!important` which overrides this styling)

Mind posting the code snippet ?