# Javascript problem in catching data on looping

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I try to loop multiple values from a database and every time I click a specific item on the menu, Javascript only catches the first value that comes up in the database even if the function is inside the loop, Even I click the last item, the first item still displays... How to fix? Here is my code. (The display of the result is on top, I didn't include it)

```
<?php
    $res = mysqli_query($db,"select * from menu where Restaurant_id='$id' order by Food_name asc") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($db));
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $f_id = $rows['Menu_id'];
            $fname = $rows['Food_name'];
            $fprice = $rows['Price'];                      
?>

    <div class="col-12 helv menu rounded">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-expand-md">
      <li class="nav-item"><img class="rounded" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="180" height="180"></li>
      <li class="nav-item marginleft">
          <br>
          <input id="foodname" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" style="display: none;"><h5><b><?php echo $fname;?></b></h1></input><br>
          <input id="foodprice" value="<?php echo $fprice;?>" style="display: none;"><h5>Php <?php echo $fprice;?>.00</h1></input>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 90%">
        <button class="fa fa-plus btn btn-danger" onclick="add()"> Add</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    </div>

<script>
      function add() {
          var fdname = document.getElementById("foodname").value;
          var fdprice = document.getElementById("foodprice").value;
          document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = fdname;
          document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = fdprice;
      }
  </script> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Welcome. There can be only one HTML (DOM) element with a given ID. Your `add` function needs to be outside of the loop and take argument(s) which depend(s) on the item. Also, please take a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), because your SQL queries seem quite unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  // As Jeto said, you should use prepared statement
  $res = mysqli_query($db,"select * from menu where Restaurant_id='$id' order by Food_name asc") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($db));
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      $f_id = $rows['Menu_id'];
      $fname = $rows['Food_name'];
      $fprice = $rows['Price'];                      
?>
  <div class="col-12 helv menu rounded">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-expand-md">
    <li class="nav-item"><img class="rounded" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="180" height="180"></li>
    <li class="nav-item marginleft">
        <br>
        <input class="foodname" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" style="display: none;"><h5><b><?php echo $fname;?></b></h1></input><br>
        <input class="foodprice" value="<?php echo $fprice;?>" style="display: none;"><h5>Php <?php echo $fprice;?>.00</h1></input>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 90%">
      <button class="fa fa-plus btn btn-danger" onclick="add('<?php echo $fname;?>', <?php echo $fprice;?>)"> Add</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  </div>
<?php } ?>

<script>
  function add(fdname, fdprice) {
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = fdname;
      document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = fdprice;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First get count of how many items are in there before the while query

```
$res = mysqli_query($db,"select * from menu where Restaurant_id='$id' order by Food_name asc") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($db));

$count_of_items = mysqli_num_rows($res);
```

Then run the while query, then Run a for loop inside the form as per the number of Items

```
for($x=0;$x<count($count_of_items); $x++){
<input id="foodname" value="<?php echo $fname[$x];?>" style="display: none;"><h5><b><?php echo $fname[$x];?></b></h1></input><br>
      <input id="foodprice" value="<?php echo $fprice[$x];?>" style="display: none;"><h5>Php <?php echo $fprice[$x];?>.00</h1></input>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some more mistakes.

## 1) IDs are unique

Please check this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889416/3742228

## 2) Duplicate JS function

Every loop you make, you create another JS function named "add". If you create 3 functions named "add", which function do you want to call when you code add()? :)

---

For your code there are more solutions, but it depends on what exactly you want to do. Take a look at this:

```
<?php
$res = mysqli_query($db,"select * from menu where Restaurant_id='$id' order by Food_name asc") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($db));
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        $f_id = $rows['Menu_id'];
        $fname = $rows['Food_name'];
        $fprice = $rows['Price'];                      
?>

<div class="col-12 helv menu rounded">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-expand-md">
  <li class="nav-item"><img class="rounded" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="180" height="180"></li>
  <li class="nav-item marginleft">
      something here
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 90%">
    <button class="fa fa-plus btn btn-danger" foodName="<?php echo $fname;?>" foodPrice="<?php echo $fprice;?>" onclick="add(this)"> Add</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
</div>


<?php } ?>
  <script>
  function add(e) {
      var fdname = e.getAttribute("foodName");
      var fdprice = e.getAttribute("foodPrice");
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = fdname;
      document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = fdprice;
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: `button` element should have `data-foodname` and `data-foodprice` attributes instead of `foodName` and `foodPrice`, shouldn`t it?

Comment: No, you can put what name you want as attribute, instead of name/id/class, etc.

Comment: @MihaiZinculescu This is bad practice as this would produce an invalid document (though [some proposals](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2271) exist to change that).