# Is it possible to use same id for different HTML elements?

Tags: html, tags

I m trying to check all the checkboxes on the basis of their values but it only checked the first row. I don't know how to assign a value to the same id elements

**HTML code:**

```
<tbody class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; overflow: auto;">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.DetailList)
                    {
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FormCode, new { @id = "formCode" }) - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FormName)
                            </td>

                            <td style="text-align:center;">

                                <input type="checkbox" id="view1" name="view" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="add1" name="add" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="edit1" name="edit" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="delete1" name="delete1" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="post1" name="post" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="print1" name="print" />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
```

Comment: It is not recommended and also pointless. Have different IDs and loop on name or class. Also post rendered HTML and script in a [mcve]

Comment: Just loop on `document.querySelectorAll("tbody [type=checkbox]:checked")`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but don't do that.

Element IDs should be unique, you can use other things like `class` on your elements to group them with something in common.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but it ruins the point. An id is used to uniquely identify elements, use classes if you want to target multiple elements

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it) Stackoverflow-post