# complex .css : Specifically I just am confused with this, and need to apply display: none; to this entire Menu Section without defecting its function

Tags: css, class, drop-down-menu, nested

Confused about the hierarchy for applying .css when mixing .class and #id
I would like the .css that will make this entire subsection of the menu display: none; 
EDIT : Yes, the first suggestion did remove the submenu, but also removed the other items, I should have posted the entire Menu first time.
  This spits out Menu where I do want some available and some not.
Overview Yes
Reerrals No
Payments No
Help No
Logout Yes
Marketing and its submenus - NO 
  Profile and its submenus - Yes

```
<div class="uap-ap-menu">
<ul>
<li class="uap-ap-menu-tab-item `enter code here`"><a href="https://mywebsite/?uap_aff_subtab=overview"><i class="fa-uap fa-overview-account-uap"></i>Overview</a></li>
<li class="uap-ap-menu-tab-item "><a href="https://mywebsite/?uap_aff_subtab=referrals"><i class="fa-uap fa-referrals-account-uap"></i>Referrals</a></li>
<li class="uap-ap-menu-tab-item "><a href="https://mywebsite/?uap_aff_subtab=payments"><i class="fa-uap fa-payments-account-uap"></i>Payments</a></li>
<li class="uap-ap-menu-tab-item "><a href="https://mywebsite/?uap_aff_subtab=help"><i class="fa-uap fa-help-account-uap"></i>Help</a></li>
<li class="uap-ap-menu-tab-item "><a href="https://mywebsite/?uapaction=logout"><i class="fa-uap fa-logout-account-uap"></i>LogOut</a></li>
<li class="uap-ap-submenu-item"><div class="uap-ap-menu-tab-item"  ><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="uap-ap-menu-sign fa-uap fa-account-right-uap" id="uap_fa_sign-profile"></i>Profile</a></div>
<ul class="uap-public-ap-menu-subtabs" style="" id="uap_public_ap_profile">
</ul>
</li>
<li class="uap-ap-submenu-item"><div class="uap-ap-menu-tab-item"  ><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="uap-ap-menu-sign fa-uap fa-account-right-uap" id="uap_fa_sign-marketing"></i>Marketing</a></div>
<ul class="uap-public-ap-menu-subtabs" style="" id="uap_public_ap_marketing">
</ul>
</li>
<li class="uap-ap-submenu-item"><div class="uap-ap-menu-tab-item"  ><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="uap-ap-menu-sign fa-uap fa-account-right-uap" id="uap_fa_sign-reports"></i>Overall</a></div>
<ul class="uap-public-ap-menu-subtabs" style="" id="uap_public_ap_reports">
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `.uap-ap-submenu-item {display: none;}` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, it di-d remove the submenu but also removed the other submenu items, I reposted the full menu, just wanted everything else display none, and still show the Profile submenu and its children, thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

It's because in css rules any id value has much stronger effect than class, so selector with id ALWAYS override selector with class.
Please, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889404/6919578)