# Show/hide div based on two option condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to display/hide elements based on the combination of the two select boxes. I've tried the following method when "values" was selected for eg. when we select the optional "in" and "spare" then that results is the "spare-in" id being shown.

```
<select id="test1">
  <option value="in">in</option>
  <option value="out">out</option>
</select>

<select id="test2">
  <option value="spare">Spare</option>
  <option value="faulty">Faulty</option>
  <option value="rma">RMA</option>
</select>

<div id="in spare" >
   spare-in id is ...
</div>
<div id="in faulty" >
   rma-in id is ...
</div>
<div id="out spare" >
   spare-out id is ...
</div>
<div id="out rma" >
   rma-out id is ...
</div>
```

Comment: What has PHP got to do with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this.

> HTML will not allow you to add 2 id's. instead it will consider as single id even you have spaces between it.
>
> so, in my solution I replaced your id with classes.

```js
$("select").change(function(){
  var test1 = $("#test1").val();
  var test2 = $("#test2").val();
  $(".in, .out").hide();
  $("."+test1+"."+test2).show();
  
});
```

```css
.spare,.faulty,.rma {
  display: none
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test1">
  <option value="in">in</option>
  <option value="out">out</option>
</select>

<select id="test2">
  <option value="spare">Spare</option>
  <option value="faulty">Faulty</option>
  <option value="rma">RMA</option>
</select>

<div class="in spare" >
   spare-in id is ...
</div>
<div class="in faulty" >
   faulty-in id is ...
</div>
<div class="in rma" >
   rma-in id is ...
</div>
<div class="out spare" >
   spare-out id is ...
</div>
<div class="out faulty" >
   faulty-out id is ...
</div>
<div class="out rma" >
   rma-out id is ...
</div>
```

Comment: @NikunjKathrotiya https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/multiple-ids-in-a-div/6257/3. see this multiple id for same element is not allowed

Comment: See my example it's working not multiple id it's space between two words

Comment: That are not 2 id's there it will consider as single id. It may work for you now for a small part of code. it is not the right way. please google about it.

Comment: Read again question and see html code what is current requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193252/discussion-between-syed-mohamed-aladeen-and-nikunj-kathrotiya).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.you can also try this with onchange event of your dropdown list rather than submit button.

```js
$("#submit_btn").on("click",function(){
var data=$("#test1 option:selected").val();
var data1=$("#test2 option:selected").val();
if(data=="in" && data1=="spare")
{
$("#inspare").show();
}
});
```

Comment: use inspare as your first <div> id .

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onchnagefunction()
{
  var test1value = $('#test1').val();
  var test2value = $('#test2').val();
  document.getElementById(test1value+" "+test2value).style.display = "block";
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("div").hide();
    onchnagefunction();
    $('#test1').on('change', function() {
        $("div").hide();
       onchnagefunction();
    });
    $('#test2').on('change', function() {
        $("div").hide();
       onchnagefunction();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="test1">
      <option value="in">in</option>
      <option value="out">out</option>
    </select>

    <select id="test2">
      <option value="spare">Spare</option>
      <option value="faulty">Faulty</option>
      <option value="rma">RMA</option>
    </select>

    <div id="in spare">
       spare-in id is ...
    </div>
    <div id="in faulty" >
       rma-in id is ...
    </div>
    <div id="out spare" >
       spare-out id is ...
    </div>
    <div id="out rma" >
       rma-out id is ...
    </div>
```

Tested and working check this.

Comment: Why are you calling onchange 3 times instead of calling only once with the select element?

Comment: i don't understand your comment and 
why down vote my answer give me a proper reason @SyedMohamedAladeen

Comment: see my answer I have done with just a single onchange. you have made 3 onchanges which is not required considering the load time.

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen you know different between id and class i think you not understand basic concept of id and class

Comment: run your snippet and my snippet. then you will feel the run time difference.

Comment: your snippet is very slow and bed code for this question  and you wasted my time see the different between id and class : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it  @SyedMohamedAladeen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193254/discussion-between-syed-mohamed-aladeen-and-nikunj-kathrotiya).

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen what is the problem in my code please explain it. It's working fine

Comment: $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
        $("div").hide();
       var test1value = $('#test1').val();
  var test2value = $('#test2').val();
  document.getElementById(test1value+" "+test2value).style.display = "block";
    });
});

Comment: something is wrong in your comment check again and why deleting your previous comments and you waste my and your time and your code is working on class base and user asked to id based and i don't understand why user accepting your answer @SyedMohamedAladeen