# dynamically replace same div ids with unique ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I was wondering if there's simple JS/JQuery to change the div ids inside the container from `'one'` to unique ids (like `'one_1', 'one_2', 'one_3'`)

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
</div>
```

## Desired Output

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="one_1">ONE</div>
  <div id="one_2">ONE</div>
  <div id="one_3">ONE</div>
</div>
```

I've gotten so far as to extract the three divs, but now need to replace the text:

```
document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll("#one")
```

Comment: Are you unable to update the source code to fix this issue?

Comment: Get rid of the id and use a class instead.

Comment: If you've got the list of three divs, just loop over them and set their `id` properties.

Comment: I can change the 'one' from id to class if that makes it easier to create unique IDs, but i don't know how to then change the properties from 'one' to 'one_1' etc etc. I can't update the source code and the number of inside divs will be changing dynamically

Comment: If you are using a class, *why* do you need unique ids?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-to-use-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the version of [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) which takes a function as its second parameter:

```js
jQuery(($) => {
  $('#container > div').attr('id', (index, id) => `${id}_${index + 1}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
</div>
```

Or, if you can't use ES6+ Javascript:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('#container > div').attr('id', function (index, id) {
    return id + '_' + (index + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just loop over the container's children and update their IDs:

```
var children = document.getElementById('container').children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var child = children[i];
  child.id = child.id + "_" + (i + 1);
}
```

Comment: I actually like this best.  no jQuery, simple and to the point.  of course OP is using jQuery so it is only a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution:

```
$("#container div").each(function( index ) {
 this.id = this.id+"_"+(index+1);
});
```

Single line (thanks to [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas)'s comment)

```
$("#container div").attr("id", (index, oldId) => oldId + "_" + (index + 1))
```

Comment: `.attr("id", (index, oldId) => oldId + "_" + (index + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".changer").on("click",function(){
var i = 1;
$("#container").children().each(function(){
 var id = this.id;
 $(this).attr("id",(id + "_" + i));
 i++;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
</div>
<button class="changer">
Change IDs
</button>
```