# Jquery not handling href click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a delete hyper link

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" id="delCategory">Delete</a>
```

and my Jquery function

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#password_validate").validate({
            rules:{
                current_pwd:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength:6,
                    maxlength:20
                },
                new_pwd:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength:6,
                    maxlength:20
                },
                confirm_pwd:{
                    required:true,
                    minlength:6,
                    maxlength:20,
                    equalTo:"#new_pwd"
                }
            },
            errorClass: "help-inline",
            errorElement: "span",
            highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
            }
        });
        $("#delCategory").click(function(){
            alert("Test");
            if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Category?')){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

---

My other parts of the code can access the `#password_validate` and make sure the password field is required and all. But the `#delCategory` from the same HTML page is unable to access the function and return confirmation.

I am able to call the Jquery function from Chrome Console and get the pop-up and confirmation, but my href is failing to call it and it processes the delete without confirming.

Comment: Where is your _delete_ logic, to begin with?

Comment: In the Controller. Its Laravel based.

public function deleteCategory($id = null)
    {
        if(!empty($id))
        {
            Category::where(['id' => $id])->delete();
            return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Successfully Deleted Category');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_error', 'Failed to Deleted Category');
        }
    }

Comment: Well, your `confirm()` demo seems to work just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/theAccountant/Lwrune25/     What specific challenge are you currently experiencing?   Did you try putting the _delete_ logic inside the `if...` statement of your `$("#delCategory").click...` event handler?

Comment: Yes thats the problem. I can call the function from Console in browser by $("#delCategory").click(), but when I physically click the href - it doesn't call the js and directly goes to the controller and performs delete. I have the JS inside a js file and the PHP code inside a controller

Comment: Are you using a `<form>` to submit the __delete__ request or is it an `$.ajax(...)` call?

Comment: No form No ajax. Just a href click and Jquery to handle the click

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229888/discussion-between-steven7mwesigwa-and-hariharan-thiagarajan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `event.preventDefault()` to your `click(...)` event handler to prevent the default action/behaviour that belongs to the event from occurring. i.e:

[Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```html
<form  method="POST" action="{{ url('/admin/delete-category/'.$category->id) }}">
    @csrf
    @method("DELETE")
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$category->id}}">
    <input id="delCategory" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-center btn-mini" value="Delete">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```js
$("#delCategory").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Category?')) {
        return;
    }

    const $form = $(this).closest("form");

    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        data: {
            "_method": $form.find("input[name=_method]").val(),
            "_token": $form.find("input[name=_token]").val(),
            "id": $form.find("input[name=id]").val()
        }
    });
});
```

**ADDENDUM**

If you have multiple "**delete**" buttons in a single document, you may consider using a `class=...` attribute instead of `id=...`.i.e:

```html
<!-- Instead of: -->
<input id="delCategory" ...> ❌

<!-- Use this: -->
<input class="delCategory" ...> ✅
```

Modify the JavaScript accordingly. i.e:

```js
$(".delCategory").click(function (e) {
    // ...
```

That would ensure that the event handler is applied to **all** relevant 'dom' elements with a [particular `class` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead of a [single dom element matching a **unique** `id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id).

*Resources:*
[What's the difference between an id and a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/whats-the-difference-between-an-id-and-a-class)

[What is the difference between id and class in CSS, and when should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889362/what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-class-in-css-and-when-should-i-use-them/12889421#12889421)