# how i can select this element with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, selector

in the code bellow how can i select the span element with id="read-more" if iam in the anchor element with id="preface-more-btn" using $(this) (to be applied for more than one button) in jquery?

```
<pre>
   <div id="content">
       <p>
           <span style="font-size: 16px;"></span>
       </p>
       <span id="read-more" style="display: none;"></span>
       <div class="more active" id="preface-more">
           <a class="btn-more" id="preface-more-btn" href="#"></a>
       </div>
   </div>
</pre>
```

thank you for helping..

Comment: Have you searched yet? It's extremely trivial to search by ID...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var selector = $('#read-more');
```

It is globally unique since it is has an ID.

EDIT:
Try

```
$(this).parent().prev();
```

Comment: "to be applied for more than one button"

Answer (score 2):

If you're contextually *within* the element with `id="reface-more-btn"`, you can select it intuitively like this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('#read-more');
```

If you're looking for readability, try this:

```
$(this).closest('#read-more');
```

But since the `id` is unique to only *one* element, why aren't you just using `$('#read-more');`?

You might be confusing `class` and `id`, as only *one* element can have a certain `id`, while many elements can share a `class`. Read this question for a longer explanation, as it's *essential* to know the differences: [div class vs id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84378/div-class-vs-id).

Comment: @Jeff: He states "to be applied for more than one button", even thought *that* is wrong.

Comment: The OP might be confusing `id` and `class`.

Comment: if the OP already has a JQuery command that he is calling on the button maybe he just wants to chain that with what he wants to do with #read-more, so he saves a line and avoids searching the DOM

Answer (score 0):

This will always work:

```
$("#read-more");
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the structure will always look like it does:

```
var theSpan = $(this).parent().parent().find('#read-more');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, selecting an element by id is quite easy.

```
$("#read-more")
```

Will do it regardless of where you are because the id's are global.

Comment: "to be applied for more than one button"

Comment: @Blender, I know, but that is what he is asking. But I think your answer pretty much covers that as well.

Comment: I'm saddened by OP's who don't conceptually understand HTML and want to use jQuery. There should be a test that should be taken before being allowed to download the library...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#read-more') will do the trick
```