# PHP / JQuery clone hidden table row, add to end of table

Tags: php, jquery

I've got a table, with the first TR hidden (style="display:none;"). I have a button at the top of the table to allow users to add a new row to the table.  When clicked, I would like the hidden row to be cloned and added to the bottom of of the table. I'm thinking this is the best way as I can pre-format the row to contain exactly what I need in the NEW row.

Here is the JQuery I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
   $(".dispadd").click(function() {
      $('#hiddenrow').clone().show().appendTo( $('#hiddenrow').parent() );
   });
});
```

It appears to add the row as expected, but within a second, the new row disappears.
Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

__*_*__ *LATEST CODE* __*_*____

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".dispadd").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#hiddenrow')
            .clone()
                .removeAttr('id')
                .show()
                .appendTo( $('#disptable').after().show() 
        );
    });
});
```

I had to modify it a bit after having to move the #hiddenrow outside the parent table.  How do I set the value of one of the inputboxes in the cloned row?

Comment: what if you move show to the end?

Comment: How about `.removeAttr('id')` as that's probably making it hidden / non-displaying? All rules that make `#hiddenrow` hidden... might apply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, so some other code on your page must be hiding the new rows. Most likely this is because you aren't removing `#hiddenrow` from the cloned rows - see below:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".dispadd").click(function() {
        $('#hiddenrow')
            .clone()
                .removeAttr('id')
                .show()
                .appendTo( $('#hiddenrow').parent() );
    });
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kelervin/4zrC7/2/

Comment: After clicking the button and having the new row appear then quickly disappear, I check the source and it's not there either.

Comment: Firebug allows you to set a breakpoint when a child is added or removed - that should help you track down what's removing the rows. Inspect the table, then right click on it in Firebug's DOM tab and click 'Break on Child Addition or Removal'

Comment: I think I'm narrowing it down.  My table is wrapped by a form.  When the form is submitted, it processes it, then repopulates the form with new database data.  Is there something can add to the JQuery to keep the button from submitting my form?

Comment: Yep, `event.preventDefault()` will take care of that - see http://jsfiddle.net/kelervin/4zrC7/3/

Comment: I really appreciate your help Kelvin!  And everyone else that offered suggestions!

Comment: Not a problem - glad to help! :)

Comment: Another issue within the same topic; First, I had to move the #hiddenrow outside the parent table.  It was getting picked up by the form as a blank record.  Now, I need to set a value for one of the inputboxes in the cloned row.  How would I set that?  I have edited my original post with my current code.  Thanks!

Comment: Use `find()`, `end`, and `val()` on the cloned row: `...clone().find('input[name="myinput"]').val('newvalue').end().show()...`

Answer (score 1):

A follow up note - if you don't remove the id #hiddenrow from the newly cloned row, you end up with more than one rows with the same id - see here: [div class vs id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84378/div-class-vs-id)