# Table row delete using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have made this code to remove table row :

```
jQuery('tr#rowAttend1').remove();
```

HTML :

Three rows with same id .
For example :

```
<tr  id="rowAttend1" ><td>ssss</td></tr>
<tr  id="rowAttend1" ><td>ddddd</td></tr>
<tr  id="rowAttend1" ><td>ccccc</td></tr>
```

but 
i want all three to be removed
it works fine in all browsers except ie7 ?
Can anybody help me?

Comment: id's should not be same either make them unique or use class..

Comment: please post your jquery code and html code here <script> to </script> <table> to </table>

Comment: Would give example by using class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84378/div-class-vs-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr  id="rowAttend1" ><td>ssss</td></tr>
<tr  id="rowAttend2" ><td>ddddd</td></tr>
<tr  id="rowAttend3" ><td>ccccc</td></tr>

$('#rowAttend1,#rowAttend2,#rowAttend3').remove();
```

Change the ids to unique ids and then you can remove the table row

Class example

```
<tr  class="rowAttend1" ><td>ssss</td></tr>
<tr  class="rowAttend1" ><td>ddddd</td></tr>
<tr  class="rowAttend1" ><td>ccccc</td></tr>

$('.rowAttend1').remove();
```

This will remove all elements with the class `rowAttend`

Answer (score 1):

Your ID is not unique please use different ID for  like,

```
<tr  id="rowAttend1" ><td>ssss</td></tr>
<tr  id="rowAttend2" ><td>ddddd</td></tr>
<tr  id="rowAttend3" ><td>ccccc</td></tr>
```

(OR)

Pass particular eventcatch(e) (i.e) (this) to that javascript function and remove from that this like,

```
$(this).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

some different way try if u like

```
<table>
    <tr><td>one</td> <td><button class="removeTR"> one</button></td> </tr>    
    <tr><td>two</td> <td><button class="removeTR"> two</button></td> </tr>    
    <tr><td>three</td> <td><button class="removeTR">three</button></td> </tr>    
    <tr><td>four</td> <td><button class="removeTR"> four</button></td> </tr>    
   <tr><td>five</td> <td><button class="removeTR"> five</button></td> </tr>    
</table>

$("tr .removeTR").live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

or some thing that gives good smooth row deleting

```
$("tr .removeTR").live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(1000);
    setTimeout(function(){$(this).parent().parent().remove();}, 1000);
});
```