# Find class inside ID and change attribute of element

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="myclass" id="myid">
```

Trying to use the following to search for the element with this ID inside this class:

```
var getDiv = document.getElementById("myid").getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0];
getDiv.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden");
```

This returns `getDiv` as 'undefined'

I will have numerous elements with the same class or ID, but only one element exists on the page with both.

Comment: Why do you need to grab the element by ID *and* class? Isn't the ID alone sufficient?

Comment: `same class or ID` not ok!

Comment: "*I will have numerous elements with the same [...] ID*" - What. That's not valid. An ID is supposed to uniquely identify an element.

Comment: you can't have repeated IDs, that's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is invalid. Id is only used for one element, and class is used for multiple. And you can only do this:

```
var something = document.getElementById("myId");
something.setAttribute(...);
```

or

```
var something = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass"); //this is now array of elements
something[0].setAttribute(...); // I chose first element
```

I hope this helps. To find out more about id vs class click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84378/div-class-vs-id).