# Locate duplicate div ID names on page and append a number using Javascript orr jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am required to use a specific plugin in Wordpress for a project. It outputs several DIVs, each with identical IDs.

However, I need to isolate them individually, so that I style them in CSS separately.

Normally I would either alter the PHP or use nth-child...but this plugin basically makes both of these options impossible...long (and frustrating) story.

So I am looking for a Javascript/jQuery solution that I can plug into a global .js file and execute using a $(document).ready statement after page load instead.

I just can't seem to figure it out. The js/jquery code would need to alter the html output by this plugin after it's finished loading. It would scan the page, locate each instance of #commonName, and append a number onto it OR add a class name to it. Doesn't matter how it's done, as long as each DIV becomes unique in name.

The plugin outputs something like this on the page (simplified):

```
<div id="commonName"></div>
<div id="commonName"></div>
<div id="commonName"></div>
```

I would like my Javascript or jQuery code to locate and change every instance of this ID, and turn it into this:

```
<div id="commonName" class="copy-1"></div>
<div id="commonName" class="copy-2"></div>
<div id="commonName" class="copy-3"></div>
```

Or this would be fine too:

```
<div id="commonName-1"></div>
<div id="commonName-2"></div>
<div id="commonName-3"></div>
```

Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: ID should be unique and Class can be duplicate you have the other way around.`<div class="commonName" id="copy-1"></div>
<div class="commonName" id="copy-2"></div>
<div class="commonName" id="copy-3"></div>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [div class vs id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84378/div-class-vs-id)

Comment: I wrote my post wrong - ignore the ID in my sample code. The class names are what is a duplicate...I am in need of something in jquery that can locate all the duplicate class names and make them unique - perhaps by appending a number to it or something like that.

Comment: Guradio - yep makes sense, I wrote my sample code wrong. What you wrote is exactly what I need to have happen with jquery or javascript....That's actually how it is output right now, except the class names are all identical. I need a solution preferably in jquery/javascript that will append some numbers to make all the class names OR ids all unique,,,,

Answer (score 0):

This will take all of the `ids` that have the id value of `commonName`
The using an `each` loop, we can change the id value using the `attr` function.

Hope this helps :>

```js
$("[id='commonName']").each((i,el)=>$(el).attr('id','commonName-'+i))

console.log($("body").children())
```

```css
body div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}


#commonName-0{
  background: red;
}

#commonName-1{
  background: green;
}

#commonName-2{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="commonName"></div>
<div id="commonName"></div>
<div id="commonName"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo BLANCO -- you nailed it! Super elegant code by the way works flawlessly and outputs into the console commonName-0, commonName-1, commonName-3. I did have one quick question --- how would I go about replace these IDs with the new ones you prodiuced directly on the page instead of outputting into the console?

Comment: They actually change in the page. What you see in the console is the page status after the change. You can inspect the page to see this happening

Comment: Added some css so you can see the ids change in the page.