# How to remove elements from table in Javascript..When Elements are In different <TD>

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
function AddFileUpload1() {
    if (document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer1").childElementCount < 4) {
        var div1 = document.createElement('DIV');

        div1.innerHTML = '<div id="MyCoolDiv1"><table><tr><td><input id="file' + counter1 + '" name = "file" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg"/></td><td><input id="Button" type="button" value="Remove" Class="btn btn-default" onclick = "RemoveFileUpload1(this)"/></td></tr></table></div>';
        document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer1").appendChild(div1.firstChild);
        counter1++;

    }
}
```

No matter which button is clicked it removes the first element above code creates control dynamically.

```
function RemoveFileUpload1(div1) {

    var myCoolDiv1 = document.getElementById("MyCoolDiv1");

    document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer1").removeChild(myCoolDiv1);
}
```

Above code removes the first element no matter which button is clicked...

Comment: because you are using `id` as `id`  is meant to be unique. So, only one selection is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only able to remove the first element as you are using the `id` `MyCoolDiv1`.
And as `id`'s are meant to be unique in `HTML`. So, when you make the query:

`var myCoolDiv1 = document.getElementById("MyCoolDiv1");`

It is always going to give you the first implementation of the element with the given id (i.e. `MyCoolDiv1`). So, to have a better understanding on id you can refer to [When to use class or id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84416/2417602).

and below is an implementation of your function with an optimized approach.

```js
var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');

function AddFileUpload1() {
  var ChildCount = myTable.querySelectorAll('tr').length;
  var counter = ChildCount + 1;
  if (ChildCount < 4) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML = '<tr><td><input id="file' + counter + '" name = "file" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg"/></td><td><input id="Button" type="button" value="Remove" Class="btn btn-default" onclick = "RemoveFileUpload1(this)"/></td></tr>';
    myTable.appendChild(tr);
  }
}

function RemoveFileUpload1(div1) {
  var get_tr = getParent(div1, 'tr');
  get_tr.remove();
}

function getParent(ele, parent) {
  while (ele.localName != parent) {
    ele = ele.parentElement;
  }
  return ele;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="AddFileUpload1()">
Add
</button>
<div id="FileUploadContainer1">
  <table id="myTable">

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: ..you made my day..can u suggest me some books or website to understand such concepts more clearly as i am new in it..

Comment: most of our knowledge will come only after experience but for practice, you can refer to [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/default.asp) or you can look at this playlist [kudvenkat](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhUA99nOsJkKXBqokT3MBK0b)