# 2 Dropdrows with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 dropdowns with same id on  each select tag , something like this :

dropdown 1:

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number. id="Id" name="Id">...</select>
```

dropdown 2 :

```
<select class="form-control" id="Id" name="Id"><option value="21">Pre-Production</option>
<option value="18">In Viability Test </option>
</select>
```

Right now im calling the Ids like this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Id").change(function () {
...  $("#Id").empty();  ...
```

This is how the both dropdowns are generated in html:

```
div class="card-body">
                    <form action="#">
                        <div class="form-group-feedback form-group-feedback-left"">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Class1.OfType<Class1>().FirstOrDefault().Id, Model.SelectedListClass1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

div class="card-body">
                    <form action="#">
                        <div class="form-group-feedback form-group-feedback-left"">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Class2.OfType<Class2>().FirstOrDefault().Id, Model.SelectedListClass2, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

The problem is that #Id from first  and  form other dropdown have same #id (select#Id-form-control).

I would like to know how can i distinct those ids using jquery.

Comment: You shouldn't have two elements with the same ids. IDs should be unique

Comment: IDs HAVE to be unique. That's the point of them

Comment: You can add a class to distinct them. but you don't need two id to be the same

Comment: @Bosco i have same ids because im calling them from collections <types> from one model, and the id of those collections types are named Id.

Comment: @PedroMendes then you may need to change something as duplicate ids means your html is invalid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [div class vs id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84378/div-class-vs-id)

Comment: Id is like your last resort of identification, you either use class, name, id, tag name to identify an element. Since you have exhausted tag type, id and name, that is why I suggest using class to differentiate them. basically this class is not doing anything. like others said the Id being same is an invalid `Html`. If you can show your collection, the we can know the better way to implementing  generating you html

Comment: @bosco can i have some practical exemple of using class instead id? Aditionally i have updated my question with html code that is generating Id = id.

Comment: Can you show `Class1` and `Class2`? but at the point where you have class you can do `@class = "form-control class_one"`, also `class_two`. But since you have two classes you can still use id

Comment: @Bosco thx, that should fix my problem , but instead naming the class i will change the id names like ...@class = "form-control", id = "Class1Id" and "Class2Id".... Once again thx for the solution ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you are doing with 'Id' should be done through 'class' or 'className' in react,
because 'id' is supposed to be unique for every tag.