# Id and class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Maybe my questions are stupid because I am beginner in JavaScript

1. Why is there is `classList` but there's not `idList`
2. Why do some people prefer to use **`getElementById`** instead of **`getElementByClassName`**

Comment: 1: how would you have an element with multiple IDs? 2: because they want to look up an element by its ID, not by its class

Comment: I prefer neither, `querySelector[All]` trumps both.. :)

Comment: IDs and classes are attributes on DOM elements. IDs must be unique to identify _one_ element in the page. An element can zero or more classes.

Comment: getElementById("id") is superior to querySelector("#id") due to the specificality of the ID

Comment: @mplungjan  Could you elaborate on what you mean by,  specificality of the ID?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Every element can only have 1 id so there is no need for a list.

Question 2: getElementByClassName is not a function. getElementsByClassName is (notice the plural "elements"). getElementsByClassName returns a list of elements while getElementById returns only one element. Use getElementsByClassName is better when you want to get multiple elements.

I would recommend querySelector and querySelectorAll. They take CSS selector queries instead.

Comment: Worth mentioning the difference between methods like `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelector` - the former returns a live HTML collection, the latter a static (non-live) node list.

Comment: @Andy you mean querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Every element can only have one id, hence there is no requirement for an idList.

Question 2: You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84416/18609846) . However, there are times where the id selector can outperform the class selector in speed. Which one to use (getElementById or getElementsByClassName) in these circumstances is up to you.